# How to get all commit messages which are affected in last push in git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I am just trying to create a git hook which sends a notification about all the commits to our ms-teams channel on every "post-recieve".

The git hook itself works, but with the command `git log -1 --pretty=format:'%s'`
I only get the last commit-message, which is not very useful if you push multiple commits to master.

Is there a way to get the data (message, author, date of commit, commit number, usw.) of all affected commits on every push?

I have looked up a lot of questions here on Stack Overflow, but haven't found a proper solution for my problem.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006695/how-to-get-all-hashes-that-are-being-committed-in-a-pre-receive-hook) for pre-receive also work for post-receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically speaking, your `origin/master` will be the position of `master` on the remote `origin` after your last synchronisation. `master` will be your current branch. The commits between these will be the ones you're interested in and you can get them using `git log origin/master..origin` and you can do whatever you want with these.

Now, in your case, you need to run this on the server after a receive. I'm not sure that `post-receive` will have this information (since the references will already have been updated). However `pre-receive` hook receives a list of all the commits that are being pushed. Perhaps hooking up this to your notification function would help better. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000712/how-to-get-all-commit-messages-which-are-affected-in-last-push-in-git) linked to from [Lasse V. Karlsen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000712/how-to-get-all-commit-messages-which-are-affected-in-last-push-in-git#comment106112662_60000712) has details on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had about the same need, on my side. I needed the list of comments made on each commit after a certain tag to generate a kind of changelog list.

You know that **post-receive** gets the old and new values of all refs in addition to their names.

The parameters sent to your script will be of the form: `<oldrev> <newrev> <refname>`

So you'll just have to do: `git log $1..$2`