# How do i restrict commit messages for dev/master branches only

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to use GIT hooks to restrict commit message formats (e.g. "`must start with #`") on my main branches only: dev, master. I do want to allow contributors to have their own custom commit messages on their private branches.

Example: If someone has X commits on their private branch "`commit1"...."commitX`", can I use hooks to block them from merging to or into `dev`/`master` branches telling them that only commits starting with "`#`" are allowed?

Comment: What code have you written already? Where are you having problems? (That's how stackoverflow works.)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by enforcing this rule on commit messages? Seems a bit draconian.

Comment: Yes i agree. However this is not my repo, it's my employer's, and I am trying to get a bit more freedom of commits on private branches, as i do like to stack my changes, and following convoluted commit message rules for every checkpoint doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use hooks to block them from merging to or into dev/master branches

Not easily one the [client side](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) (because they need to be deployed on all clients, and they can be bypassed anyway)

What is usually done is set up a [server-side](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) hook which will block any push including commits with an incorrect message.
[The `update` hook can be more suited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524125/6309) for this than the `pre-receive` one.
See "[Customizing Git - An Example Git-Enforced Policy](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#Server-Side-Hook)"