# How to fix "corrupted" interactive rebase?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-rebase

I managed to create a little mess in my local git repository. I was trying to fix a broken commit by using the [following instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit). Before running the "git commit --amend" (and after the git rebase --interactive) I decided that my changes were incorrect and so I executed "git reset HEAD --hard". Not a good idea, I tell you.

Now the interactive rebase seems to be "stuck". Git shows the current branch as (|REBASE-m). Every command (cd .., ls, git rebase...) inside my repository gives the following error:

> cat: .git/rebase-merge/head-name: No such file or directory

Here's how git rebase --abort looks like:

```
$ git rebase --abort
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/quiet: No such file or directory
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/head-name: No such file or directory
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/orig-head: No such file or directory
HEAD is now at 4c737fb Revert "Modified file names"
rm: cannot remove `c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/done': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove directory `c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge': Directory
not empty
cat: .git/rebase-merge/head-name: No such file or directory
```

Here's the result of git rebase --continue:

```
$ git rebase --continue
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/prev_head: No such file or directory
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/end: No such file or directory
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/msgnum: No such file or directory
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/onto: No such file or directory
cat: c:/_work/project/src/git/.git/rebase-merge/quiet: No such file or directory
prev_head must be defined
cat: .git/rebase-merge/head-name: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? I would like to reset the situation back to the state it was before I started my well-thought rebase operation.

Here's how git log --oneline shows the situation:

```
4c737fb Revert "Modified file names"
247ac02 Modified file names
33141e6 Message modifications
10a4a04 Modified db script
```

And this is fine.

I'm using msysgit v1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

It looks like Git tried to remove the `.git/rebase-merge` directory but wasn't able to remove it completely. Have you tried copying that folder away? Also copy away the `.git/rebase-apply` folder if that is present.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was able to fix my problem just by restarting the computer. I'm not sure what went wrong because somehow every access to the .git\rebase-merge folder caused an "Access denied" -error.

Comment: Reboot did not work for me but `git rebase --abort` (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4757777/146044) _did_ work.

Comment: a word of warning... i had 4 hours worth of changes on my working directory when i noticed the corrupted rebase error. tried the `git rebase --abort` it wiped my unstaged changes... the error did disappear though

Comment: Removing REBASE_HEAD, rebase-apply/ and rebased-patches in .git worked for me

Comment: `git rebase --quit` worked for me but I lost all autostashed changes like @GeorgeAnandaEman => it is possible to recover them though by using the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845799/how-do-you-get-a-lost-autostash-commit-from-git-rebase-autostash explaining how to see all autostash commits

Comment: For IntelliJ users: Git > Rebase... > Abort Rebase.

Comment: yeah, I deleted .git/rebase-merge and the rebase was fully gone.  Easy fix. I was using Merge , by sublime-text. I hate that app, im done with it

Answer (score 801):

I got stuck in this. I created the head-name file, and then I ran into another error saying it couldn't find the onto file, so I created that file. Then I got *another* error saying could not read '.git/rebase-apply/onto': No such file or directory.

*So* I looked at the git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---quit) for rebasing and found another command:

```
git rebase --quit
```

This set me back on my branch with no changes, and I could start my rebase over again, good as new.

Comment: `--quit` worked. `--abort` didn't because the rebase was cancelled half way through

Comment: I had similar rebase-related error, just with different error message. Tried: `$ git rebase --abort` Output: `error: could not read '.git/rebase-apply/head-name': No such file or directory` Finally, this solution fixes my problem: `git rebase --quit`

Comment: Upvoted. `git rebase --quit` absolutely saved me. Same symptoms as described, but mine came after trying to do a `git pull --rebase`, which for some reason failed. Note I had autostash enabled (git version 2.27.0.windows.1) and had VS2019 running (pointed at that repo) at the same time - suspect some combination of these messed it up.

Comment: I was worried I'd have to re-do all the rebasing work after `git rebase --quit`, so I backed up the whole tree first, but after quiting and starting the rebase again, there were no conflicts to resolve! I might have been helped by my "rerere" configuration set up before the rebase started. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere

Comment: As said in comments of the accepted answer, `git rebase --quit` will wipe the `.git/rebase-merge` folder, **including autostash**. If you had an autostash (with `git rebase --autostash`), make sure to save its commit hash (found in `.git/rebase-merge/autostash`) before running this command so you can easily reapply it afterwards with `git stash apply <hash>`.

Answer (score 94):

I had a similar problem due to a zombie vim.exe process. 
Killing it in Task Manager, followed by a `git rebase --abort` fixed it.

Comment: this was my problem too. I used sysinternals `handle` command and saw that a process (sh.exe) had the file locked. Using `pskill <pid>` fixed it for me.

Comment: i tried git rebase --abort but got an error error: could not read '.git/rebase-apply/head-name': No such file or directory; git rebase --quit worked

Answer (score 41):

Thanks @Laura Slocum for your answer

I messed things up while rebasing and got a detached HEAD with an

```
 error: could not read orig-head
```

that prevented me from finishing the rebasing.

The detached HEAD seem to contain precisely my correct rebase desired state, so I ran

```
rebase --quit
```

and after that I checked out a new temp branch to bind it to the detached head.

By comparing it with the branch I wanted to rebase, I can see the new temp branch is exactly in the state I wanted to reach.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Had same problem in Eclipse. Could not Rebase=>abort from Eclipse.

Executing **git rebase --abort** from Git Bash Worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, if you are unwilling or unable to restart the machine see below.

Install Process Explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

In Process Explorer, Find > File Handle or DLL ...

Type in the file name mentioned in the error (for my error it was 'git-rebase-todo' but in the question above, 'done').

Process Explorer will highlight the process holding a lock on the file (for me it was 'grep').

Kill the process and you will be able to abort the git action in the standard way.

Answer (score 6):

Create a file with this name:

```
touch .git/rebase-merge/head-name
```

and than use `git rebase`

Comment: touch: cannot touch '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory

Comment: `warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory`. then `warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/onto': No such file or directory`. then i create onto, and it throws the next error: `error: invalid onto: ` after i run `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 6):

In my case eighter `git rebase --abort` and `git rebase --continue` was throwing:

> error: could not read '.git/rebase-apply/head-name': No such file or directory

I managed to fix this issue by manually removing: `.git\rebase-apply` directory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `git version 2.19.2.windows.1`.

the only thing that worked for me was to remove the `.git/rebase-apply/` directory and do a `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried all the above steps mentioned but nothing worked for me. Finally, **restarting** the computer worked for this issue :D

Comment: this is what worked for me. Danke!

Answer (score 2):

With SublimeText 3 on Windows, the problem is fixed by just closing the Sublime windows used for interactive commit edition.

Answer (score 2):

If you get below state and rebase does not work anymore,

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto (null)
You are currently rebasing.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
```

Then first run,

```
$ git rebase --quit
```

And then restore previous state from reflog,

```
$ git reflog
97f7c6f (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: pull --rebase: checkout 97f7c6f292d995b2925c2ea036bb4823a856e1aa
4035795 (master) HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): Adding 2nd commit
d16be84 HEAD@{2}: commit (amend): Adding 2nd commit
8577ca8 HEAD@{3}: commit: Adding 2nd commit
3d2088d HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to head~
52eec4a HEAD@{5}: commit: Adding initial commit
```

Using,

```
$ git checkout HEAD@{1} #or
$ git checkout master #or
$ git checkout 4035795 #or
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I had opened SmartGit's Log in the respective Git project and Total Commander in the respective project directory. When I closed both I was able to rebase without any problem.

The more I think about it, the more I suspect Total Commander, i.e. Windows having a lock on opened directory the git rebase was trying to something with.

Friendly advice: When you try to fix something, always do one change at a time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have satisfactorily completed rebasing X number of commits , the last command must be `git rebase --continue` . That completes the process and exits out of the rebase mode .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used process explorer as suggested in other post (i am not able to find that post) and figured out which process has a lock on the file and kill it. then execute the --continue or --abort as per needs

Answer (score 0):

In my case after testing all this options and still having issues i tried `sudo git rebase --abort` and it did the whole thing

Comment: Be careful if you're doing this in the middle of an actual rebase. Just lost my changes :'(

Comment: It was considered "corrupted", then you start over with the rebase

Answer (score 0):

tried everything else but a reboot, what worked for me is `rm -fr .git/REBASE_HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

I had a commit running in my VSCode that made it stuck. killed the VS Code process and did recover (R) to the rebase. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the "author-script" because it was already used in the last commit I did (on accident). I undid that last commit, and committed everything in one. (I'm using git-branchless fwiw)

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions mentioned above directly resolved my issue, but they did point me in the right direction and helped me identify where to focus my efforts. Ultimately, I was able to find a different solution that addressed my problem effectively.

When executing `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, I encountered an issue completing the rebase due to my operating system being **Windows 10 21H2** and using **Git version 2.43.0**, and I was using GitBash(even specifying to run it with administrator privelegies did not resolve the issue).

It threw me the following error: `warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory.` I then created that file as suggested above. However, it produced another error: `warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/onto': No such file or directory.` Subsequently, I created `onto`, and it threw the next error: `error: invalid onto: after I ran git rebase --continue`. It did not show any errors in the terminal, but `VS Code` and `CMD` did.

I opted to try a different terminal and observe the outcome. Utilizing `VS Code` with `CMD`, I proceeded to execute the `git rebase -i HEAD~3` command, which resulted in the following errors:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:\Users\UtmostCreator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code: line 14: realpath: command 
not found
C:\Users\UtmostCreator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code: line 14: dirname: command not found
C:\Users\UtmostCreator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code: line 14: dirname: command not found
C:\Users\UtmostCreator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code: line 22: uname: command not found
C:\Users\UtmostCreator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code: line 22: sed: command not found
C:\Users\UtmostCreator\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code: line 61: /Code.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code'.
```

Before changing your editor you may have a look at your default editor by executing this command:

```bash
git config core.editor
```

**Solution is to**

Specify/Set the absolute path to my Visual Studio Code editor (or another editor of your choice) using the following command:

```bash
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Users/UtmostCreator/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe' --wait"`
```

You can see how you can add other editors from official docs [git config core.editor commands](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C%3A-Git-Commands-Setup-and-Config#ch_core_editor).

Or Use a different terminal as it may show you more errors.

In this command, the parameter `--wait` instructs Git to wait for us to process and close the file. Please replace the path with your own editor of choice (and dont forget to addd single quotes if you have space in you path).

Or add your editor to `PATH` variable, [which should be added by default as VS Code docs says](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows). It was really strange as It was opening the VS Code editor from GitBash, so it should know the editor's `PATH`, and how to open it.

Answer (score -3):

I am using git in eclipse and I was having the same problem.

Eventually I found that the "Rebase ..." menu entry was temporarily transformed into a sub-menu.

Team-> Rebase -> Abort

It worked for me.