# interactive git rebase failed with "git-rebase-todo: No such file or directory"

Tags: git, cygwin, rebase

when I do interactive git-rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

it shows:

```
C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe: /cygdrive/xxx/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo: No such file or directory Nothing to do
```

(`xxx` is the project path)

but `git rebase branch_xxx` is working.

I am sure no rebase is in progress previous(checking with `git rebase --abort` and use clean project folder both)

have some one solved this ? I google it but wihtout useful tips.

Comment: Is the full path of git-rebase-todo shorter than 250 characters ?

Comment: @Andrei Podoprîgora yes, it's shorter than 250 characters. the interactive git rebase work correctly before. I don't known whether I have changed some environment variable that can effect this. for there are some days that I havn't exec this command.

Comment: in this case it's another issue. Maybe you will find an answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685001/git-how-to-fix-corrupted-interactive-rebase

Comment: thanks, I try it but seems not the same as my problem, I think I need a re-install of my cygwin and git.

Answer (score 17):

My problem was due to my gitconfig missing the -w and -n flags:

```
[core]
    editor = sublime -w -n
```

From [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651608/Git-Setting-Sublime-Text-as-the-Default-Editor-for):

> [The -w and -n arguments are] passed to Sublime Text, and essentially
>   tell it to run without loading any previously open windows (the –n
>   flag), and to wait until the user exits to pass execution back to the
>   calling process (the –w flag, for "wait")

Comment: Whoever downvoted, tell me why please. I could see downvoting, maybe, because this is could be a mac-only solution. But the error I was experiencing that led me to this post is the same error message. And my solution fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For vs code it means that forgot to pass the wait flag to code.

wrong:

```
    editor = code
```

correct:

```
    editor = code --wait
```

Comment: good lord, this worked for me. thanks @felix-ht, stuck on this for way too long