# Git rebase failing

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-rebase, rebase

I'm trying to rebase the work of a colleague.

First, I get a ton of conflicts where <<<<< head seams to contain the new code.

Then after a while I get the following error:

```
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/dev_504': 
cannot lock ref     'refs/heads/dev_504': ref refs/heads/dev_504 is at
 XXXXXXX 
 but expected     XXXXXXXX
Could not move back to refs/heads/dev_504
```

Then if I try to continue anyway I get the following error:

```
fatal: cannot resume: .git/rebase-apply/final-commit does not exist.
```

How can I fix this so the rebase won't give an error?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685001/git-how-to-fix-corrupted-interactive-rebase. might help

Comment: Did you try starting over after a `git rebase --abort`?

Comment: what was the 1st command you used ?

Comment: "git rebase --abort" worked for me!

Answer (score 23):

- You can run `git rebase --abort` to completely undo the rebase. Git will return you to your branch's state as it was before git rebase was called.
- You can run `git rebase --skip` to completely skip the commit. That means that none of the changes introduced by the problematic commit will be included. It is very rare that you would choose this option.
- You can fix the conflict.
- Failing that, you should re-create your branch or you can be able to remove the .git/rebase-merge directory, which contains the rebase state.

Comment: I'm not sure the third point (fix the conflict) applies. OP has already fixed the conflict, the error message appears after running `git rebase --continue`

Comment: ` % git rebase --skip                                                                                                                  :(
git: builtin/am.c:1981: am_skip: Assertion `!is_null_oid(&state->orig_commit)' failed.
error: am died of signal 6`

Answer (score 10):

Apparently the branch onto which you want to rebase, was also rebased between the time you branched off, maybe cleaning history up or rebasing on yet another branch. If so, you need to:

- abort, current mess:`git rebase --abort`
- to be current: `git fetch`
- now the interesting part:

  `git rebase --onto BUDDY_BRANCH YOUR_BRANCH~ YOUR_BRANCH`

e.g.
you branched of your local *master* (checkout of origin/master),  a new branch *test_branch* (which you now want to update with current origin/master)

```
git rebase --onto master test_branch~ test_branch
```

What this does is in simple terms, it takes your branches initial parent commit, finds it's counterpart in current master and rebases based on that.

Comment: This is the real answer! To rebase your local master branch onto origin/master, enter  `git rebase --onto origin/master master~ master`

Answer (score -2):

When you are updating your local branch with the another branch, you must resolve conflicts by choosing between your modifications and theirs.
After resolving conflicts you can continue your rebasing by writing this git command :

`git rebase --continue`

In case when you want to abort your action of rebasing you can write this git command :

```
`git rebase --abort`
```