# How do you get a lost "autostash" commit from `git rebase --autostash`

Tags: git, rebase

When using `git rebase --autostash`, git automatically creates an "autostash" commit, and will re-apply it after a successful rebase.

But in case the rebasing is aborted (e.g. by using `:cq` in Vim when it's an interactive rebase), the autostash-commit might end up as a dangling commit.

Git 2.9.0

Comment: If you *interrupt* an interactive rebase, the interactive rebase should still be in progress, and `git rebase --continue` will resume it, while `git rebase --abort` should terminate *and* re-apply the autostash.  If it does not re-apply the autostash, that's a bug (I'm pretty sure there was such a bug for a while, so your Q+A is actually useful, but if you have the bug, you should upgrade your Git).

Comment: After all it's probably a but with git in the first place - it should not leave this autostash behind: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/297404.

Comment: @torek the rebase is not in progress afterwards anymore, so it cannot be aborted or resumed. `git rebase --continue` says `No rebase in progress?`.

Comment: Ah, definitely a bug then.  I take it you're making the *sequence* editor fail, during the rebase startup.  Aha, yes, that's in your bug report.  You can simplify this by replacing your steps 2-and-3 with just `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=false git rebase -i --autostash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git 2.10 (Q3 2016) should avoid that issue entirely.

See [commit 33ba9c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33ba9c648b6753a4184e53ffb89f0a924f9f7b7e) (29 Jun 2016) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5eb1e9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5eb1e9f1a0df41cfc6a75cef9c2f11460a6da8dc), 13 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `rebase -i`: restore autostash on abort
>
> When we abort an interactive rebase we do so by calling `die_abort`, which cleans up after us by removing the rebase state directory.
>   If the user has requested to use the autostash feature, though, the state directory may also contain a reference to the autostash, which will now be deleted.
>
> **Fix the issue by trying to re-apply the autostash in `die_abort`**.
>   This will also handle the case where the autostash does not apply cleanly anymore by recording it in a user-visible stash.

Answer (score 22):

I have found the following to list all "autostash" commits:

```
git log --pretty='%cr: %h %s' $(git fsck --no-reflog \
  | grep '^dangling commit' | cut -f3 -d\ ) | grep ': autostash$'
```

You can then use the commit hash to get the commit back, e.g. using `git show` or `git cherry-pick`.

The output looks like this:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
2 minutes ago: 7a50bcb On improve-moving-out-of-zoomed-tmux-pane: autostash
22 minutes ago: 9c504af On pr-123: autostash
5 weeks ago: f216b45 On look-for-vim-with-pgrep-ps: autostash
9 weeks ago: f405faa On look-for-vim-with-pgrep-ps: autostash
10 weeks ago: 28ddead On look-for-vim-with-pgrep-ps: autostash
```

Comment: Rebase stuffs the hash of the autostash into a "state directory" in `.git` (`$state_dir` in the rebase script; see `$(git --exec-path)/git-rebase`, `apply_autostash` function, around line 160). Assuming you're dealing with the Git bug and this state dir is gone: Once you have the ID, use `git stash store` to turn it into a regular stash (see same code, around line 167).