# git pull --rebase does not tolerate any modified files at all, contrary to git pull --no-rebase

Tags: git

Please, observe:

```
C:\xyz\55 [release/r-855 ↓1 +0 ~16 -0 !]> git pull --rebase
error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: please commit or stash them.
C:\xyz\55 [release/r-855 ↓1 +0 ~16 -0 !]> git pull --no-rebase
From http://server.xyz.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/code/_git/xyz
 * [new branch]          wfm/tfs485759 -> origin/wfm/tfs485759
Updating 5f010c356..871eb9ca2
Fast-forward
 .../PayrollService/DAL/Payroll/PayRunDataProviderDAL.cs            | 7 ++++++-
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
C:\xyz\55 [release/r-855 ≡ +0 ~16 -0 !]>
```

My conclusion is that `git pull --rebase` does not tolerate any modified files at all. This is unlike `git pull --no-rebase`, which is OK as long as none of the modified files clash with the new commits.

This kinda sucks.

Is my conclusion correct? Or can `git pull --rebase` be configured to behave more like `--no-rebase` when it comes to modified files?

Comment: If you want to use merge instead of rebase for one particular pull - git pull --no-rebase ;
If you want to apply all your yet-to-be-pushed commits on top of the remote tree commits allowing your commits to be straight in a row and without branches, then use  - git pull --rebase ;

Comment: I do not understand how this comment is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase`, contrary to `git merge` (which is done by a normal pull) requires a clean working tree.
(`git merge` only requires that the merged files are not currently modified)

To get that clean working tree automatically, use `git config --global rebase.autostash true`.
That way, your `git pull --rebase` will work.

---

Warning though:

"[`git pull --rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7a9ae6d0d9cf979a2b1a018135370dd6331e505c/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L108)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalse%7Ctrue%7Cmerges%7Cinteractive))</sup> ignored the `rebase.autostash` configuration variable when the remote history is a descendant of our history, which has been corrected with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022).

See [commit 3013d98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3013d98d7a09b42a111a355db286e72ee03b2e94) (13 Jan 2022) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7a9ae6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a9ae6d0d9cf979a2b1a018135370dd6331e505c), 05 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`pull --rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3013d98d7a09b42a111a355db286e72ee03b2e94): honor `rebase.autostash` when fast-forwarding
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Tilman Vogel</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> "`pull --rebase`" internally uses the merge machinery when the other history is a descendant of ours (i.e.
> perform fast-forward).
> This [came from this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqa8cfbkeq.fsf_-_@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/), where the discussion was started from a feature request to do so.
>
> It is a bit hard to read the rationale behind it in the discussion, but it seems that it was an established fact for everybody involved that does not even need to be mentioned that fast-forwarding done with "rebase" was much undesirable than done with "merge", and more importantly, the result left by "merge" is as good as (or better than) that by "rebase".
>
> Except for one thing.
>
> Because "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3013d98d7a09b42a111a355db286e72ee03b2e94/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> does not (and should not) honor `rebase.autostash`, "[`git pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3013d98d7a09b42a111a355db286e72ee03b2e94/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))</sup> needs to read it and forward it when we use `git merge` as a (hopefully better) substitute for "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3013d98d7a09b42a111a355db286e72ee03b2e94/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> during the fast-forwarding.
>
> But we forgot to do so (we only add "`--[no-]autostash`" to the "`git merge`" command when `git pull` itself was invoked with `--[no-]autostash`" command line option.
>
> Make sure "`git merge`" is run git with `--autostash` when `rebase.autostash` is set and used to fast-forward the history on behalf of rebase".
>
> Incidentally this change also takes care of the case where
>
> - "[`git pull --rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3013d98d7a09b42a111a355db286e72ee03b2e94/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L108)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---rebasefalse%7Ctrue%7Cmerges%7Cinteractive))</sup> (without other command line options) is run
> - "`rebase.autostash`" is not set
> - The history fast-forwards
>
> In such a case, "`git merge`" is run with an explicit `--no-autostash` to prevent it from honoring `merge.autostash` configuration, which is what we want.
> After all, we want the "`git merge`" to pretend as if it is `git rebase` while being used for this purpose.

Comment: If the rebase fails, it won't auto un-stash; you'll need to use `git stash pop` or equivalent for that when you're ready, and the documentation warns that you can also get conflicts when it applies the stash. There's a reason it defaults to false; I find it useful, but it might make conflict resolution harder.

Comment: @DanielH  Agreed. Unless it is an interactive rebase. If the rebase fail and you want out, do a `git rebase --abort`: that will restore the autostash (since Git 2.10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38436051/6309)