# Git rebase error: No such file or directory

Tags: git

I was going to do a rebase to update my last commit but I didn't want to finish so I exited. (I realize this probably was not the best way to go about it, but it's done) I guess I did it wrong because I am getting the error:

```
su@sun-PC MINGW64 /e/learninggit/git_learning (|REBASE-m)
$ git rebase --continue
error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
```

How do I get rid of this error so I can continue making commits? 
I have no effect using the `git rebase --abort` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - How to fix "corrupted" interactive rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685001/git-how-to-fix-corrupted-interactive-rebase)

Answer (score 3):

`git rebase --quit` will exit rebase mode while leaving your working tree unchanged