# How do I edit the commit message of any commit in git?

Tags: git, commit-message

Let's say I have 3 unpushed commits. Now I want to change the commit message of the first or second commit (changing them for the third one is simple using `git commit --amend`). How to do that?

Comment: That is a bit similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926768/amend-a-commit-that-wasnt-the-previous-commit. I tried (below) to see how a `commit --amend` could be scripted. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To rebound on the sub-question: is there a `git commit --amend` for a previous commit (and not just the last one), you could try something like (not tested yet, but [Colin O'Dell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158766/colin-odell) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940266/how-do-i-edit-the-commit-message-of-any-commit-in-git/3940887#comment36791399_3940887) having written a script for it [**colinodell/git-amend-old**](https://github.com/colinodell/git-amend-old)):

```
git checkout -b tmp
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git commit -amend 
git rebase --onto tmp HEAD@{1} master
```

That would be like:

```
x---x---x---x---x
                ^
                |
               (master*) (* = current branch)

git checkout -b tmp
x---x---x---x---x
                ^
                |
               (tmp*, master) 

git reset --hard HEAD~2
x---x---x---x---x
        ^       ^
        |       |
      (tmp*) (master) 

git commit -amend 
      y (tmp*) 
     /
x---x---x---x---x
        |       ^
   (HEAD@{1})   |
          (master) 

git rebase --onto tmp HEAD@{1} master
    (tmp)
      y---x'---x' (master*) 
     /
x---x---x---x---x (only referenced in reflog)
```

Comment: On the `rebase --onto`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491

Comment: why bother? rebase -i is much simpler

Comment: @CharlesB: I agree, `rebase -i` is simpler, but it also *interactive*. Meaning you cannot include it in a script or in an alias grouping a sequence of commands.

Comment: I've created a Bash script inspired by this answer: https://github.com/colinodell/git-amend-old  Hopefully somebody finds it useful.

Comment: @ColinO'Dell nice one! i have included a link to your script in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for the powerful [`git rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command. Also, see the [Interactive Rebasing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html) section of the Git book.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but can `git rebase -i` be used non-interactively?

Comment: No, not as such. However, everything that `git rebase -i` does can (in theory) be done using other, scriptable Git commands. So it would be possible to write a script to modify a previous commit message, but I don't know whether such a thing exists yet.

Comment: congrats on your 15th gold badge ;) You are now a true git! (Err... git-guru, I meant) (I mean, guru about the tool name git) (I mean, you know what I mean)

Comment: @VonC: Thanks, that one kind of snuck up on me!