# Rebasing a Specific SHA1

Tags: git

If I have the following commits

```
38deab3 Bug Fix# 10
f33fb65 Bug Fix# 20
4fa0485 Bug Fix# 30
```

Why does `git rebase -i f33fb65` allow me to edit 38deab3 and not f33fb65? Why do I have
to run `git rebase -i 4fa0485` to edit f33fb65?

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926768/amend-a-commit-that-wasnt-the-previous-commit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a base commit to `rebase` on top of, some commit that will not change, since doing anything other than a pick during an interactive `rebase` will change the sha id for the commit...unless, of course, you squash/fixup a following commit into the picked commit!

The point is, the `rebase` command won't know ahead of time how you will `rebase` your commits, so it needs a base commit that is guaranteed not to be changed by the `rebase`.

Answer (score 6):

*git rebase seems to rebase up to the specified commit (whether you do it via commit SHA or e.g. `HEAD~4`).*

So you should use the commit relative notation to select the commit you know and want to tinker with!

```
$ git rebase -i <SHA>~1
```

This includes your specified commit (as your going up to the one before it)

**Syntax**:

```
$ git rebase -i <SHA>~<number>
```

This will select from the most recent commit up to not including the `<number>` more commits that the one you chose!

## Example

With an example commit history like so:

```
  aaa    first commit
  bbb    add a function
  ccc    add terrible colour scheme
  ddd    another function
  eee    my most recent function
```

And you want to remove that terrible colour scheme change in the commit `ccc`

You would enter and get the following output.

```
$ git rebase -i ccc~1

pick  ccc    add terrible colour scheme
pick  ddd    another function
pick  eee    my most recent function
```

Answer (score 3):

Because rebase is applying commits after the one you choose. You are rebasing on this chosen one so you say "take f33fb65 and reapply everything I have after it".

Answer (score 3):

`git rebase -i 4fa0485` means : rebase my current branch (say `master`) on top of `4fa0485`. As such, it will let you edit all commits starting after `4fa0485` until `master` last commit.