# Git: How do I edit the message of a previous commit that is not the latest one?

Tags: git, edit, commit-message

I just realized that I left one word in the commit message of a previous commit (so I can't use git commit --amend) that makes the message mean completely the opposite of what I had intended.

The commit in question is HEAD~2 on my current branch, which is ahead of the branch base.  How can I edit just the message on that commit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)

Comment: Sure, the answer in the other question does apply but my question is more simple and the chosen answer is, likewise, simple and concise.  That has value.

Comment: It does. I'm just marking this question as duplicate, I'm not saying we need to remove it or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interactive rebase and mark that commit with `r` (reword):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Don't use rebase if your history was already made public

Comment: Okay, I didn't push this branch.  So I'm supposed to use that command on the parent of the commit I want to change?

Comment: You just want to have your commit in that list, so either the parent or the branch base will work in this case... in most cases you want to rebase from the branch base to reword/reorder/squash commits in the entire set of commits you are about to push.