# Git --amend in Eclipse JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, git, git-amend

I tried to Push some files in git
For example a,b,c,x,y,z files..

I did commit ammends after i found some mistakes int he files...
I did commit amend for same files and pushed same files a,b,c,x,y,z

After Some commits I realized that , i dont want file "C" instead I want file  "D".
I added file "D" and did commit amend..

Now everything goes fine but now I could see all files after commit amend
a,b,c,d,x,y,z
but I dont want to send C file to git
I want remove file C after doing commmit amend and 
want to see only
a,b,d,x,y,z files
I am using Eclipse,JAVA for doing this process

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's Java and NOT JAVA.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I will correct it next time!!

Comment: I tried to delete the old file C.Added file d and did commit amend again in Eclipse
I could see file C with CROSS symbol and File D
Should I click FINISH by clicking File D and File C (with CROSS symbol)in Eclipse ?

Comment: Thank you anyways Everyone!!
My Problem is solved, Delete the file, do commit-amend ,
In eclispe you can see the delted file with check box and updated new file with check box. click both check boxes , and click finish.
you will get rid of file c and file d will be added.now i can see only a,c,d,x,y,z.
thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Git's --amend option only allows you to amend the last commit. If you want to amend commits you have done sometimes ago. You need to follow this:
[How to modify a specified commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)