# Rename directory throughout Git commit history

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm trying to rename a directory that was introduced six commits ago and in all subsequent commits. These commits have not been pushed.

**What have I tried?**

- I've tried using `git filter-branch` with an `mv old new` command, but this fails on commits before `HEAD~6` because the directory doesn't exist.
- I've tried `git rebase -i HEAD~6`, editing each commit, but I can't use `mv old new` because git's locking the file, nor can I rename it in Windows Explorer.
- I've tried the same rebase with `cp -R old new; rm -rf old; git add new` but this creates merge conflicts on `HEAD~4` and above.

It may be worth noting that the commit on which this directory was introduced is the first commit in this branch (the branch is six commits ahead of `master`) and that I haven't touched `master` since I branched out.

I've also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1186535/732016).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: why not simply start a new branch (at master) and then do a simple swap between the old and the new branches at ~N and pick off the 6 commits in a row (e.g. cherry-pick & git mv old new & commit). It may not be 'fast' but it would be quite quick.

Comment: @PhilipOakley excellent suggestion! I hadn't used `cherry-pick` before but that worked quite well. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git filter-branch` should work fine; just make the `mv` command fail gracefully by appending `|| true`. For example, to rename `baz/` to `foo/bar/baz/`:

```
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter \
    'mkdir -p foo/bar; mv baz foo/bar/ || true' \
    --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 2):

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch states:

To move the whole tree into a subdirectory, or remove it from there:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
            git update-index --index-info &&
     mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain how it works? In particular, what is the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable used for? (I get what the replacement pipeline does, but not the destination.)

Comment: I'm not sure, trying to find out the details.. for now just copy pasting the examples. And it does work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply start a new branch (at master) and then do a simple swap between the old and the new branches at ~N and pick off the 6 commits in a row.

For example `git cherry-pick` & `git mv old new` & `git commit`.

It may not be 'fast' but it would be quick enough with only 6 commits to fix.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, please add some context.