# Git Working tree is dirty

Tags: gerrit, git-commit, git

If I execute `git review` git shows me "Working tree is dirty" error.

I made a commit and I sent to review. After that I update the branch from the upstream using `git pull`. Now I need to modify the previous commit message, so, there are my commands:

1) `git reset <id-of-the-commit-to-modify>`

2) `git commit --amend`

vim was opened to modify my commit. But here appears information about my commit and others commits as well and I don't know why. However, I modified the commit message and write/close vim.

3) `git review`

This command raise this error:

```
Errors running git rebase -i remotes/gerrit/master
doc/source/configuration.rst: needs update
doc/source/developing.rst: needs update
tools/sample_data.sh: needs update
Working tree is dirty
```

What I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `git status` tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git reset <id-of-the-commit-to-modify>` without a mode option is defaulted to `--mixed` . This is what is said on the reset in the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html)

```
--mixed
 Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.
```

This basically means your index has been reset, but not your working files. So all files that you pulled from upstream are still left in your working tree. 
You should use `git reset --hard <id-of-the-commit-to-modify>` This will reset your index and remove the files that came with your upstream pull. You can then amend your commit and send it for review.

Answer (score 0):

once a change was pushed to Gerrit, then it can be fetched directly. On the Gerrit review board you can find the chekcout command for each patchset, something like this: `git fetch ssh://ebalbar@gerrit.ericsson.se:29418/TCC/TitanSim refs/changes/86/129686/5 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD` Then, you can amend the commit as usual, and push the new change again. AFter that checkout your local branch and reset it with the remote branch: `git reset --hard origin/<remote_branch>` also a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/1342413) how to modify a commit which was pushed directly.