# Rewriting committed code in Git

Tags: git, rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I have a git repo that I have decided to make public, which means moving database connection info into a .gitignored file.  However, my repository history still contains the commits that I added and then removed the information.

I have tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit) using interactive rebase, but this seems to only allow me to change/reorder the commit message, not the code that was included in the commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this article from Github:

[Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

But, the most important part of the article is certainly this quote:

> Danger: Once the commit has been pushed you should consider the data to be compromised. If you committed a password, change it! If you committed a key, generate a new one.

Comment: You should post a blurb for the link, in case it becomes broken.

Comment: Just a small addition. "Once pushed, it becomes compromised" is true only for a repository that's already made public. If a repository is just being prepared for  that, nothing is compromised yet.

Comment: A-ha, thank you!  I found BFG at the link you provided, which changed everything I wanted to `**REMOVED**`  I would have preferred it just leave the changed info blank, but it'll do.  Thanks again.