# How to edit/amend commit messages for commits previous to the last in Git?

Tags: git

As shown on [this popular answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git), when I need to edit/correct the message for the last commit, I do:

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

But what am I supposed to do when I want to amend commit messages for commits previous to the last one? For instance, the 14th last commit - also considering that commits have not been pushed to remote?

Is there a way of doing this without resetting previous commits? Would `rebase` be the right thing to do in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git). Among the answers to the linked question, you'll find [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/180085/456814), which basically says to use interactive rebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need interactive rebasing as mentioned here: [How to modify a specified commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)

The difference being, instead of `edit` you'll just want to `reword` the commit in question since you just want to edit the commit message.

Here's another useful resource: https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase

**edit:** `reword` only works on versions 1.6.6 or newer as noted by the OP.

Comment: Be careful not do this when your commits have been pushed to a remote repo.  http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Comment: True. Like the GitHub link says - "Doing so may invoke the wrath of the git gods"

Comment: It works great, thanks! One thing though, after some further reading: `reword` can only be used in `Git 1.6.6` and newer.

Comment: In that case, `edit` then `git commit --amend -m "New commit message"` it will have to be I think. Thanks for bringing it to notice! I'll update the answer.