# Modifying a merge commit after another commits before push

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

Yesterday my teammate accidentally has committed a *bad* change leaking some credentials during the merge (a rough reconstruction):

```
# bad commit reconstruction
$ git pull
... no automatic merge happened ...
... some manual merge goes here ...
$ git add .                     # instead of `git add src`
$ git commit -m "merged"
```

and then committed another non-merge *good* change, but didn't push the changes:

```
# good commit reconstruction
... edit ...
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "foo bar"
```

I would like to modify the *bad* commit so the credentials could not be pushed to the remote repository. Since local commits are not pushed yet, first of all, I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549) using `git rebase --interactive HEAD~2` (an old SVN-user hoping to rebase these *bad* and *good* revisions only), but it seems not to work showing more commits than expected (the ones that have been pulled) and fully omitting that *bad* commit. As far as I understand it does not work because of the merge. The current tree is as follows:

```
* GOOD [master]
|    
* merge + BAD
|\
| |
| * pulled [remote/origin/master]
| |   
| * pulled
| |   
| * pulled
| |   
| * pulled
```

How can I modify the *bad* commit excluding the files containing sensitive data so it could become a *good* commit as well and ready to push?

Comment: Did you tried a `git rebase -p @~2`?, with `-p` to preserve the merge?

Comment: @VonC just tried it, and it does exactly what I want. Could you please add the answer so I could mark it and close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preserve the merge created by the git pull, you can do:

```
git rebase -p @~2
```

The [`git rebase -p`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) does preserve the merge commits it rebase.

```
-p
--preserve-merges
```

> Instead of ignoring merges, try to recreate them.
>
> This uses the `--interactive` machinery internally, but combining it with the `--interactive` option explicitly is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing (see [BUGS below](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_bugs)).