# Best way in fixing a bug added in an old commit?

Tags: git, mercurial

What is the best practice you encountered when wanted to 
fix a bug created in old commit?

Let suppose you have the following commits
A->B->C->D and you discover that on commit B a bug 
was added.

[Edit: A, B, C and D were already published (pushed by others)]

Would you go back on B add the fix as a new commit B' and merge
and get E:

```
A->B->C->D->E
 \->B'-----/
```

or add it the fix after D?

```
A->B->C->D->E
```

Stackoverflow suggests me that this might be a silly question but it's important to know what option you tried and what problems or benefit you got from that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)

Comment: That depends whether the commit already has been pushed or not.

Comment: Yes, the commit was pushed by another person.

Answer (score 4):

If the commit in question is already pushed to another repository (Mercurial will track this using the [commit phase](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/phases)), then I would simply make a new commit as a child of `D`. There is no real advantage of creating the bugfix as a child of `B` with a subsequent merge — noting in the commit message of `E` that this fixes a bug introduced in `B` works just as well.

If the commit that introduces the bug is still local (in the `draft` phase with Mercurial), then you should simply edit the commit before pushing it anywhere.

With Mercurial you use the included [histedit extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) for this:

```
$ hg histedit B
```

An editor opens to let you specify what you want done for each commit. Change `pick` to `edit` in the line corresponding to `B`. When you save the file and close the editor, the history editing begins. You can now fix the bug and run

```
$ hg histedit --continue
```

when you're happy with the result.

In Git you use a so-called [interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for editing history:

```
$ git rebase -i B^
```

This starts the same process as for Mercurial. Change `pick` to `edit` and close the editor. Edit the files to your liking and amend the commit before continuing the history editing:

```
$ git commit -a --amend
$ git rebase --continue
```