# Amend the second to last commit

Tags: git

If you found a bug in your last commit, you can simply recommit the last commit with

```
git commit --amend
```

But if you already committed another commit, how do you resubmit the commit before that one?

---

**Note:** I assume, you are aware, that you should only use `--amend` if you are sure no other developer already used your commit upstream

Comment: related: [How to modify a specified commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1186535)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. **commit your fixup with**

   ```
   git commit -a -m "fix commit (this one will be shifted up one line)"
   ```

   (the commit message is not important, it will be obsolete once you are finished)
2. **Now the magic:**
   rebase the HEAD to the second last commit but edit the commit message before in that way, that you **swap the last and the last but one line** in the message editor:

   ```
   git rebase -i HEAD~3
   ```

   The editor will show the last 3 comits like this:

   ```
    pick 2a06f16 this was the last commit
    pick 0dbc5ce the last-but-one commit
    pick 2e30418 fix commit (this one will be shifted up one line)

    # Rebase 011f3d0..2e30418 onto 011f3d0
    # …
   ```

   swap the last two lines so the commit message will look for example like this:

   ```
    pick 2a06f16 this was the last commit
    fixup 2e30418 fix commit (this one will be shifted up one line)
    pick 0dbc5ce the last-but-one commit

    # Rebase 011f3d0..2e30418 onto 011f3d0
    # …
   ```
3. **Check your log** with

   ```
   git log HEAD~3
   ```
4. **push the corrected commit-line** with `+` to force a new push to the already existing branch with

   ```
   git push origin +branchname
   ```

Comment: There's even shorter way of doing the same: `git commit -a --fixup=HEAD^` (or whatever commit to be fixed), then `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and you don't need to change anything, so you can just close editor and `git` will handle the fixup itself.

Comment: It's the same as your answer, the difference is that `--fixup` simply automates step 2.

Comment: can you provide another answer with your version? (you can copy and paste my answer and add your changes)

Comment: @aragaer: your comment doesn't work on my Ubuntu. I created it as answer, is there something missing?

Comment: Do you actually mean `git log -3` in step 3? I don't see how I can check my log with your provided command.

Answer (score 28):

Well, I landed on this page while searching for the same. Found a better way with many other options

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

**For VIM Editor :**

An editor will open up with the following details

```
pick 4f4f96f Added git ignore
pick d01e18c Added sample Blog

# Rebase 60e1cd3..d01e18c onto 60e1cd3 (2 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
```

press i, change `pick` to `r` or `reword`, something like below

```
pick 4f4f96f Added git ignore
r d01e18c Added sample Blog
```

PRESS `esc + : + wq`

Another window will open up, change the commit message

PRESS `esc + : + wq`

**For Notepad or Any other Editor:**

Edit as a normal text file(pick to r or reword) and save it.

Finally

```
git push -f
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest one. Also becoming used to `rebase -i` is a good habit as it is very powerful in different situations.

Comment: I used this method to add the issue number in the commit message for the second to last commit. Super easy & quick. Thanks!

Comment: Does that add/modify staged files or simply reword the commit message?

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you want to rename the second last commit, you would have to write r in front of the first line, like 'r 4f4f96f Added git ignore' in this case.

Comment: Do note that the instructions toward the end only apply if the editor is VIM. If you switched your editor to something like Notepad++ on Windows, just use it as you normally would to change the command to "e"/"edit" (if you want to completely amend, not just reword) or "r"/"reword" (to just reword) next to the commit you want to change. Also make sure to save & close the file after changing the command.

Answer (score 5):

@aragaer 's comment is even shorter way of doing the same:

```
git commit -a --fixup=HEAD^ #(or whatever commit to be fixed)
```

then

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

and you don't need to change anything, so you can just close editor and `git` will handle the fixup itself.

*Note: This doesn't work on my Ubuntu system!*

Comment: Are you a Windows user?  If not, you'll still need to edit that file; only Git for Windows treats `fixup` commits specially during an interactive rebase.

Comment: feel free to completely edit my answer, I just wanted to add aragaers comment as answer.  If this doesn't work, I  will accept my own longer answer as the correct one. I use linux and have no way of testing that on windows

Answer (score 0):

In a git GUI you can easily achieve this:

1. add a `temp` branch to the newest commit
2. reset the branch `master` to the commit before the commit you want to edit
3. cherry pick all commits from the `temp` branch one by one to `master` and edit the messages if desired
4. push the corrected commit-line with `+` to force a new push to the already existing branch with

   ```
   git push origin +master
   ```