# git: How to refresh a commit that isn't on top

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

In my working branch, I have three dependent patches. All of them not merged.

```
<commit id -1>
<Commit id -2>
<Commit id -3>
```

**How can i add new changes to `<Commit id -2>`?**

Currently here is how I am doing it.

```
git stash
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git stash apply
git add .
git commit --amend
git cherry-pick <commit id -1>
```

This is working without any problem. But is there a better way where I can commit the staged files to whichever commit I want?

Comment: Not an answer, but I use [stgit](http://www.procode.org/stgit/) for this sort of thing. It deals with patch stacks (similarly to quilt) and allows you to refresh a patch that isn't on top. It will also happily "uncommit" git commits into stgit patches

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the interactive rebase and edit the desired commit. Something like:

```
git rebase --interactive abc4321d^
```

In the editor change `pick` to `edit` or `e`. Apply the changes (`git stash pop`) and then commit them.

This way you can modify multiple old commits in the same run. To continue the rebase, and address the next commit, you will use:

```
git rebase --continue
```

At any time, if you sense that you did something wrong, you can cancel the rebase using:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Please note that rewriting the public history (a history on a repo shared with others) is a **bad habit**. You should rewrite the previous commits only if they are not yet published.

Comment: This may not be relevent to this question , I always had this doubt regarding rebase. In intreactive rebase(or while doing rebase in general ) , are there cases where I have to do rebase --continue multiple times?

Comment: @Ajay Yes, if the rebase is stopped by an edit/reword or a merge conflict.