# Why is an interactive rebase squishing my commits together?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

Let's say that I have the following three commits:

```
c - Third Commit
b - Second Commit
a - First Commit
```

I use the following commands to perform the interactive rebase (as described [in another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/1809762))

> ```
> $ git rebase --interactive bbc643cd^
> ```
>
> In the default editor, modify 'pick' to 'edit' in the line whose commit you want to modify. Make your changes and then commit them with the same message you had before:
>
> ```
> $ git commit --all --amend --no-edit
> ```
>
> to modify the commit, and after that
>
> ```
> $ git rebase --continue
> ```

The problem is that sometimes, when I'm done, the commits have been squished into one single commit (the oldest commit, `a` in my example).

It seems that it may have something to do with when there are merge conflicts to resolve, so I suspect I may be continuing incorrectly after resolving. After resolving merge conflicts, I'm unsure about whether I need to simply do `git rebase --continue` or both `$ git commit --all --amend --no-edit` AND `git rebase --continue`. It seems like in both cases, I've had merged commits at the end, but I'm not sure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if you `commit --amend` after resolving conflicts by hand you are amending the *preceding* commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed as Tobia Tesan said in the comment, the `--amend` option adds the files to the last commit instead of creating a new one.

It should work good if you drop this option.

Comment: So I should do everything the same, except AFTER resolving merge conflicts, I should do: `git commit --all --no-edit` and `git rebase --continue`?