# How to add a missing file to a commit?

Tags: git, commit

Consider I have A, B , C , D commits and push them on remote repo.

After committing D I find there is a file that should be in B commit.

How can I edit B commit and add the missing file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

This will work assuming that no one else has pulled the code from remote. If that has happened, your history is no longer yours and this is a bad idea.

1. Make sure your repo is clean.
2. `git rebase -i A`
3. In your editor, change the entry for `B` to edit.
4. Start the rebase by closing your editor. git will stop at `B`.
5. `git add file` (where file is the file you want to add).
6. `git commit --amend`. Fix the commit message and commit
7. `git rebase --continue` to get the rest of the late commits.
8. `git push --force`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use squash which is an interactive rebase. You just have to keep in mind what is the result of a **rebase**. **Anyone who have a copy of the branch will have to delete it and fetch it again** since your history was updated.

Once you are done **re-writing** history you will have to delete the remote branch or push using the `-f` to force the push.

---

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `e` for editing the content of the desired commit, make your changes and commit it. In your case add the missing file to the `B` commit.

[image]

---

You also have the --root flag in case you need it

try: `git rebase -i --root`

**--root**

```
Rebase all commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting them with
an <upstream>.

This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a branch.  
When used with --onto, it will skip changes already contained in `<newbase>`   
(instead of `<upstream>`) whereas without --onto it will operate on every 
change. When used together with both --onto and --preserve-merges, all root 
commits will be rewritten to have `<newbase>` as parent instead.`
```