# How to update custom commit in git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm learning git and I have a problem. I created a new repository on Bitbucket and I have 3 commits:

- commit A - v1.0.2
- commit B - v1.1.1
- commit C - v1.0.0

How to update "commit B" - files (removed, edit etc.)? How to delete commits A and B (on Bitbucket)?

- git rebase
- git revert
- git reset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/):

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will rebase last 3 commits. It opens approximatelly the following in your text editor:

```
pick 1111111 commit C - v1.0.0
pick 2222222 commit B - v1.1.1
pick 3333333 commit A - v1.0.2
```

It gives you opportunity to change your commits in some way. In your particular case, you want to change `pick` on line with commit B to `edit` and remove lines with commits A and C. After saving and exitting the editor, it prompts you to recommit changes that were made in commit B and delete commits A and C.

This however changes the history in your branch, so you'll have to force push to it. Be extra careful with this if you are collaborating with someone else!