# How to commit to particular branch ID without losing the top other commits?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a `git` with `branch`. In this `branch` i have `checkout` a particular commit to separate folder.

Now I have added some of files to this particular branch id with changes. now my time to save this to `git`.

But I am wondering, if I commit and `push` may it impact on other commits sits on top of this commit ID.

How to handle this scenario?

In case If I commit, will all changes, added files only will sit on respected commit only? - need clarity.

Comment: you'll have to get the changes sitting on top of the branch id first, merge/rebase them and then push your changes. Is that what you're asking ?

Comment: No, the changes on top of this ID should be there. I would like to update the changes to only on this `id` with added files. or what is the correct way?

Comment: when you say branch id do you mean commit hash ?

Comment: yes, exactly. i have `checkout` from my `git` say 8th commit from 10 existing commits, I would like to add/update to just 8th commit only without impacting the 9,10 commits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git. this will help you hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have checkout a particular commit

That is a **[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)**: you need to create a new branch where you are. It will start from the 8th commit and you can add your work in progress in it.

```
git checkout -b newBranch
git add .
git commit -m "new branch"
git push -u origin newBranch
```

Comment: Is it required to create a new branch in the website(git repo) or withing the existing checkout folder can i run these commands?

Comment: @3gwebtrain the existing checkout folder is a detached HEAD (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), so yes, you need to create a new branch, but its content will reflect the commit you had checked out, and won't impact the other commits above.

Comment: @3gwebtrain since your local folder is part of a git repo (check the output of `git status`), then yes.