# Git reset for specific files

Tags: git

I have a huge commit and I decided to split it into two commits. So I want to make somekind of `git reset` for a few files in first commit and still have my changes of theese files in git index to be able to make a next commit.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29950959/2988730

Comment: Did you commit the commit? Or is it just staged? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You can stage/unstage any files you want. If you already made the commit, you need to do an interactive rebase.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I've already commited changes so I have a one commit with its oun hash. But I haven't pushed this commit yet so I can change everything.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information so it becomes well formed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you undo the last commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/2988730)

Comment: The accepted answer here is exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/2988730

Answer (score 0):

You can just unstage the files you want, do your commit, and then restage the files you want and do the second commit.

You could always do an interactive stage, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Answer (score 0):

First unwind the stack one commit keeping everything in the index:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

Now unstage the files you don't want until the next commit:

```
git reset -- next.commit.file.txt
```

Commit again with the same message:

```
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```

(Or make a new commit message)

Now add the files for the next commit:

```
git add next.commit.file.txt
git commit -m "next commit message"
```