# append and edit a commit after pushing to master

Tags: git

After I have pushed my files to master, I realise that, I need to add few more file. Obviously, I can add, make new commit and push it again.

But is it some how possible to overwrite older push? (May be deleting the last push; add, commit and push again?)

I am sure this is already answered, but I am possibly confused about what to look at! May be the link is sufficient(and duplicate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)

Comment: The nearest to what you want to do is Jeff's answer. However, this is not really a push overwrite. To answer directly your question, no, it's not possible to delete a push.

Answer (score 1):

do like you would make a new commit.

```
git add <file>
```

then pass the amend flag

```
git commit --amend
```

now you will have to force push to the remote

```
git push <remote> <branch> --force
```

WARNING: this will rewrite your history so others will need to force pull if they have already pulled the other commit

```
git fetch <remote>
git reset --hard <remote>/<branch>
```