# git notes after BFG?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner, git-notes

I migrated from SVN to git and i had a note in each git commit referencing to SVN revision number.
After repo import i used BFG repo cleaner to clean git history from binary files and other trash. 
Unfortunately now i do not see notes when i type `git log`. I suppose BFG forgets to update references on commits for notes.
BFG leaves a *.txt report with mapping old object id to new object id in the following format:

```
0001b24011381e8885683cd1119ba4cb077fa64b c81149b1b52b9e1e1767d6141f292891d715edb5
00024eecdc31f2f6e67018f7d6f00e7c1ad03f1f 326ee3b508e3dd2934ec1f50069195f86ea1a1c7
00028e04dcc2d59bd835b447bd3a207ae481696c 3d18e9b9d3336e59d62093200b81603ffefcc747
```

Can you suggest some script to quickly fix notes given the above mapping?

PS: I am almost sure the problem is caused by not updated refs, because when i type `git notes` in second place i can see refs which are considered old in BFG repot `object-id-map.old-new.txt`

Comment: "SVN to git" ✅, What is the command you use with BFG ? BFG has not a lot an option, because it's purpose is to be simple. If you want a clean repository, maybe you should only create one commit of the last revision. If your project has not a big history or if you are the only one who work on it. It's won't be a problem. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git) post could help you, if you want change your commit.

Comment: @Stargateur it is a huge old repo. I used `java -jar bfg-1.12.14.jar -D "*.{jar,war,zip,dll,pdb}" --delete-folders "Spring"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the following bash script to transfer my notes from old objects. The solution is slow in single thread, not sure if it is safe to run several `git notes` commands in parallel.

```
while read string; do
    hashesArray=($string)
    git notes copy ${hashesArray[0]} ${hashesArray[1]}
    git notes remove --ignore-missing ${hashesArray[0]}
done <object-id-map.old-new.txt
```

Comment: I have found out than this script creates a lot of commits in reference refs/notes/commits. Would it be possible to squash all of them to get a prettier history?

Answer (score 0):

[**Edit**: Git version 2.15, released in Nov 2017, added `--state-branch` to filter-branch.  This option saves the map in a file in a branch that the first filter-branch operation creates.  Subsequent filter-branch operations will use the existing map.  So, since Git 2.15, add `--state-branch <name>` to your filter-branch operation, then use the map in the newly created branch.]

There's nothing built in to do this; you will have to write the script or program yourself. On the bright side, BFG left you the map file: that's much nicer than `git filter-branch`, which throws it away, so that the information you need to update your notes is gone.

The underlying implementation within notes is that `refs/notes/commits` (or whatever you set for `core.notesRef`) points to an ordinary commit, which you can at least in theory `git checkout` (probably into a temporary work tree you set up specially for this purpose).  This tree contains files whose names are the annotated commits—only, slightly modified.  For instance, if:

```
0001b24011381e8885683cd1119ba4cb077fa64b c81149b1b52b9e1e1767d6141f292891d715edb5
```

is a mapping entry, with `0001b24011381e8885683cd1119ba4cb077fa64b` being an old commit, and if `0001b24011381e8885683cd1119ba4cb077fa64b` has a notes entry, there will be a file whose *name* is `0001b24011381e8885683cd1119ba4cb077fa64b`—only, it might be `00/01b2...` or `00/01/b2...`.

The *nesting depth* of all these added subdirectories is managed dynamically by the notes code, with the general idea being "add as many trees as needed to making finding whether there is a note, fast; but not so many trees as to take up a lot of space in the repository when there are very few notes starting with `0001b2...`.  This fan-out is not crucial to your purposes although you may wish to maintain it for the same speed reasons.

Your job will be to find each file in this tree under its *old* name, and move (or copy) it to a *new* name that matches the new commit ID.  Since the new name in this case would be `c81149b1b52b9e1e1767d6141f292891d715edb5`, you would rename the file as `c8/1149b1b52b9e1e1767d6141f292891d715edb5`, or `c8/11/49b1b52b9e1e1767d6141f292891d715edb5`, etc.  Once you have renamed all the files (via the index: use `git mv` or `git rm --cached` and `git add` as needed), you can turn them into a regular commit object with `git write-tree` followed by `git commit-tree`.  Make the parent of the new commit be the existing `refs/notes/commits` commit, and use `git update-ref` to update `refs/notes/commits` to point to the *new* commit, and your notes should reappear, post-filtering.

(Once you have such a thing working, it would be nice to join it up with `git filter-branch` and/or BFG itself.)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks too complicated, i wrote simple script which uses `git notes copy`

Comment: `git notes copy` does the above (well ... as a *copy* rather than a move), but one note at a time (hence the slowness).  Probably fine for your case.

Comment: Filter-branch will indeed preserve its mapping on request, use e.g. `--state-branch map` and you can then `git show map:filter.map` to get the mapping.  The saved state is reloaded on entry so you can do piecemeal filtering.

Comment: @jthill yes, the --state-branch stuff went in a while ago (Git v2.15), but was never announced (why?).

Comment: Ah, didn't think to check how new it is, at a guess it's only of interest to people who need it badly enough to hunt through the docs again looking for it.