# Attempt to add changes to previous commit using git rebase -i fails

Tags: git

I'm trying to amend changes to previous commit, as described here:
[How to modify a specified commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)

So I have my changes in 'changes to be comitted' state, and I want to 'amend' them to a previous commit, so I go

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

but getting the following error:

```
Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

I can't understand what Git is complaining about, since this is the state which the changes are supposed to be in, right?

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using v1.9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as it says

> Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
> Please commit or stash them.

So first commit your changes:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'ready to rebase'
```

and then try again

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Then while rebase you can use the `ready to rebase` commit to meld into previous one.

Say you have those four commits something like

```
pick 3396a30 commit one
pick 3396a31 commit two
pick 3396a32 commit three
pick 3396a33 ready to rebase
```

then change that to

```
pick 3396a30 commit one
pick 3396a31 commit two
f 3396a32 ready to rebase      # this line changed from "pick" to "f"
pick 3396a33 commit three
```

will result in

```
commit one
commit two       # this will include "ready to rebase"
commit three
```

meaning of option `f` is

> f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
>
> s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit