# How to remove file changes from a specific commit

Tags: git, github

this is my `git log`

```
commit 1d739fb5
commit message: Merge otherBranch

commit 1c2a12b9
file change : hibernate.cfg.xml

commit 8d9a1c49
file change : db.sql
              ...


commit 7235ac29
file change : hibernate.cfg.xml
              ...
```

I just want remove `7235ac29` commit the file `hibernate.cfg.xml` file change, how do i do that?

Is it possible ?

Comment: you can revert the commit

Comment: I suggest reading this: https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html
You can remove your last commit with: `git reset --hard HEAD^`

Comment: Do you want to discard all the changes made in that commit?

Comment: hi rebelizant, i dont want discard all changes in `7235ac29 ` commit, just the file changes.

Comment: @Liyang, did you push your changes?

Comment: @Liyang, if you did not push or no one else is working on this repo, look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/3449268

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already pushed your changes then it's not a good idea to remove the commit from the history. But it's still possible to discard your changes.

I assume that you have already pushed your commit to the remote repository and you want to discard all the changes made in that commit.

In this case, you should revert the commit: `git revert 7235ac29`. It will create another commit that cancels all the changes made in the 7235ac29 commit. You will have to resolve conflicts probably.