# Edit the contents of a git commit retrospectively

Tags: git, github, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am not looking to edit the message but the commit edit itself.

The project I am working on is a Jupyter Notebook, which uses iPython, iPython runs code in In[] chunks each having an Out[] which displays the output code of each In[], in my git pushes I have been making sure to clear the outs, but one time about 5 commits ago I forgot.

The problem is, although it is a private repo, I may one day make it public and the data the code analyses is semi-confidential, as such, I would like to leave the commit in place but clear the Out[] portions only.

I know this sort of thing is frowned upon but I have no collaborators and the repo is private. There are no forks or branches.

Comment: Just use the methods from https://stackoverflow.com/q/179123/735926 then `git push -f`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify a specified commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)