# How to git commit without opening the editor for automation purpose

Tags: git

How to do a `git commit` without opening an editor for automation purpose,
I looked at other stack overflow posts and  tried the following but none of them seems to be working

```
git commit --amend --no-edit -->opens editor


git commit --amend --reuse-message HEAD --> reuses the HEAD commit which is not what I want
```

P.S I am using git version 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for `git commit`.
[-C](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit/1.7.0#git-commit--Cltcommitgt)  allows to copy the message from an existing commit. [-F](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit/1.7.0#git-commit--Fltfilegt)  takes the message from a file (or from the standard input). [-m](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit/1.7.0#git-commit--mltmsggt)  allows to pass the message right at the command line.

The option `-m <msg>` is especially interesting as you can pass it many times; git uses all passed message separating them with empty line. That is, `git commit -m Test -m Test2 -m Test3` produces a commit with the following commit message:

```
Test

Test2

Test3
```

PS. I'm not sure multiple `-m` works in git 1.7. It was too long ago
even for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [@Dethariel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999882/16172619) should appear here instead, and I would like to make the following additions if you just want to change one specific commit's message.

```
git config --global alias.reword "!f() { SHA=$(git rev-parse --short $1); GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=\"sed -i 's/^pick ${SHA}/reword ${SHA}/'\" git rebase --interactive $SHA^; unset GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR;}; f"
```

Once you type `git reword COMMITID message`, it skips the reword marking process and directly opens the message editor for that COMMITID. Once you're done editing, simply save and exit, and you're all set.

Comment: Well, the OP question was clearly about not opening an editor, because of automatization purposes. I think your solution is the answer for a different question.