# Web.config was commited way way back in commit history, is there any way to remove it so no one could see it in any commit and ever?

Tags: git, github

The `Web.config` was commited in ~2nd commit out of ~20.

I'm sure its commit was an accident, however I would ideally want to unprivate repo - so `Web.config needs to be gone from` existence and history of the universe as well as `git logs and github`. :)

Is it possible and if yes, then how? Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to have a look at [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ideally you want to include in your questions what you have tried, where you have looked, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+file+history

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't look into enough of them to notice. But thanks for an answer regardless. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write the history using `rebase` command. With some limitations:

- If you already pushed it to remote repository you would need to force push it
- If there are more changes to the file in other commits, you would have conflict on each one of them

You should do the following:

```
git rebase HEAD~20
```

- Select the commit that added `web.config` and change `pick` to `edit`
- Remove web.config file and run `git rebase --continue`

You should have no further conflicts, if this was the only commit that changed this file.

I suggest to also read: [How to modify a specified commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is such a common occurrence that it's been included in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_removing_file_every_commit).

The command will be something along the lines of

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD
```

> It’s generally a good idea to do this in a testing branch and then hard-reset your master branch after you’ve determined the outcome is what you really want. To run `filter-branch` on all your branches, you can pass `--all` to the command.