# Git rebase with pause after every commit

Tags: git

Let's say that we have two versions of a library X: v1 and v2

I'm a maintainer for another library Y which uses library X. I was using v1 of the library, and it is there in master.

Then library X has come up with a new version v2, which required me to change the way I use the library (only package changes, library X changed it's name). Version v1 is now deprecated.

However, because my library is currently being used by enterprise users, who are not willing to update to a newer version of my library that uses v2. Also I'm supposed to provide fixes to the old version by contract.

I had two branches now:

- master (uses v1)
- new_master (uses v2)

The way I made this change is by developing on master, and rebasing new_master onto master. Then I can have one commit which contains changes that change all the v1 packages to v2 packages (import lines are the only changes).

```
master       x----x----x----x----x----n
new_master   x----x----x----x----x----f
```

(after rebase)

```
master       x----x----x----x----x----n
new_master   x----x----x----x----x----n----f
```

Now, I added a new feature to my library, which needs v2 of the library X. So it will only exist in new_master. After adding the new feature, the tree became like this.

```
master       x----x----x----x----x----x----n
new_master   x----x----x----x----x----x----f----n
```

I can do the same rebase here, but the commit `n` in the master tree needs to be fixed also. I don't want to add one more fix after the `n` of new_master.

**What I get if I do a regular re-base:**

```
master       x----x----x----x----x----x----n
new_master   x----x----x----x----x----x----n----f----n----f
```

Second `f` is the new fix commit, because after second `n` commit, branch `new_master` fails to compile.

**What I need to get:**

```
master       x----x----x----x----x----x----n
new_master   x----x----x----x----x----x----n----F----n
```

Where commit `F` is the new fix commit.

**What am I currently doing to achieve this?**

- I'm solving this, by creating a new branch called `new_master2` from new_master, then removing the new feature there.
- Then I'm rebasing `new_master2` onto master.
- The commit for the new feature is lost, so I'm cherry-picking it from new_master.
- Finally I delete the `new_master` branch, and I rename `new_master2` as new_master.
- I finish this by doing a force push to the remote.

**What I'm trying to do?**

Find another way to do the same thing, without creating the temp branch `new_master2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186549/1026805) by @ZelluX. Now the steps are as follows:

```sh
$ git checkout new_master
$ git rebase -i master
# Editor opens, find my previous fix commit, and change the command to 'edit'
# If there are conflicts, fix them and continue rebasing
# Git will stop after making my old fix commit. Ensure everything compiles there.
# If you made any changes, then add them and ammend the commit
$ git add .
$ git commit --amend
# Once done, continue rebasing
$ git rebase --continue
```

This should solve the issue of making changes to the old fixup commit.

Answer (score 1):

As I unstands it is like this. You  have two branches:  master (uses v1) and new_master (uses v2).
Now you have added a new commit in branch new_master.

```
master        x----x----x----x----x----x1----n

new_master    x----x----x----x----x----x1----f----n
```

Now for you to achieve  the result below:

```
master       x----x----x----x----x----x1----n

new_master   x----x----x----x----x----x1----n----f----n
```

You can do the rebase like this:

```
git checkout new_master
git rebase master
--if there are conflicts solve the conflicts
--git add files_conflicts_you_solved
--git rebase --continue
```

What the above command will do is:
*Move the head to point to new_master branch
*Find the commit that is point of divergence for the two branches. In this case is commit x1. And make a copy of all commit on top x1 (in this case it only n commit) and paste on top x1 commit in the new_master branch.

Another solution without using rebase it would be like this:
*Create a branch from  master name dev
*Cherry pick all commits from new_master in your dev branch

Below are the commands:

```
git checkout  master
git  branch dev
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick f^..n
```

Comment: It doesn't generate conflicts if the only commit I have on master is adding new files. Also, most of my changes will be modifications to XML files, which are not being modified in new_master. In this case, there won't be any conflicts. However, I have to fix the imports in new files too, and I don't want the fixes to be going to yet another commit.

Comment: If there are no conflicts that makes the work much easier. By doing the rebase only the commit n is going to be copied on top x1 in new_master branch.

Comment: I don't want to do this, because it involves me to create a separate branch. After searching, I learned about the edit command in the interactive rebasing. I'll add my own answer on it.