# Making sure a fresh git subtree is available everytime

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a repo say `A` and I want to add a new repo B in it using `git subtree`

From inside the repo `A`, I can run the following command

```
git subtree add --prefix=.github/workflows <my-repo>.git master --squash
```

and the new repo is cloned inside `.github/workflows` folder

Now I run some find and replace commands on `.github/workflows` using `sed`.
For this reason, it's important that it's a fresh `git subtree add` so that my variables which need to be replaced are present.

So, I can do something like this

```
rm -rf .github/workflows/*
git subtree add --prefix=.github/workflows <my-repo>.git master --squash
sed -i '' -e 's/MY_LABEL/MYTAG/g' .github/workflows/*.yml
```

This will do the job, but it will unnecessarily create commits everytime I do subtree add.
However, can this be achieved using just git commands (not using rm -rf)

I plan to use this in a `pre-commit` hook so that it's always run before a user commits.
What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you do not use git submodules?

Answer (score 0):

A `subtree pull` (possibly with `squash`) would save you the `rm` command, although it might require to resolve conflict. I creates commit too and an history of the pulls made from `<my-repo>.git`.

I believe the `subtree` subcommand woud always create commits when you use it to update the subdirectory. Git [stores](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) files in a tree structure, to which each commit points to. Hence, to change a different file, the tree changes and the commit changes.

That’s said, if your repository is not shared, you may use [history rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1186535/) to change the commit that did a previous add of the subtree and update this previous commit.