# What to do if commit message doesn't match with Regex and avoids push?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I was trying to push the code and it says

```
remote: Push rejected.
remote:
remote: refs/heads/feature/ABCD-1234: 0d7591a7f67: commit message doesn't match regex: .*[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{1,}.*
remote:         Sample Push
```

What is the actual format and how do I push it?
Do I need to revert back even if I do a new commit with

```
git commit -m "ABCD-1234 Sample Push"
```

Comment: Amend the message?

Comment: I am 3 commits ahead, I tried pushing after the third commit and got the error. Not sure about how amend command works

Comment: With amend I can only change the recent commit right?

Comment: You can edit the commit message of any commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify existing, unpushed commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages)

Comment: Fwiw those kind of pre-receive hooks are super annoying - why does _every commit_ in a feature need to reference an issue (instead of just the merge)? If it’s in your power, I suggest to rethink that, or ask for it to be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify a specified commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit)

Comment: Side note: `ABCD-1234 Sample Push` does match `.*[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{1,}.*`, but `Sample Push` alone does not. In any case `.*[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{1,}.*` is a poor regex *unless* whatever regex engine is running it does left-and-right-anchored searches, i.e., it's short for `^.*[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{1,}.*$`. It would be much better to just eliminate both `.*` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In the output of `git push`, lines preceeded by `remote:`  are the output of a hook installed on the remote side.

This error isn't a message coming from git itself, but rather indicate that the maintainers of the remote repo purposefully installed a script to force the compliance to some rule (it looks like they expect a message matching that regexp, and their *intention* is probably to have a link to a ticket in their issue tracker or some code to identify a feature).

So the question :

> What is the actual format and how do I push it? Do I need to revert back even if I do a new commit with ...

can only be answered by the maintainers of that project.

Check the project's README, or see if they have some Contributing guidelines ; if you don't find your answer there, ask the maintainers directly.

Comment: I expect`commit message doesn't match regex: .*[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{1,}.*` can be taken at face value - along with `remote:         Sample Push` (The failing commit message) and there isn’t a mystery as to what’s happening, I.e. it is not something which only the maintainers can answer. Good general advice all the same.

Comment: @AD7six : granted, however we don't know what comes next : is the number checked a ticketing system ? does the hook apply to the head commit, or to all commits in the branch ? ... I thought it was important to highlight that, since this message *isn't* a message coming from git, asking on StackOverflow (a generalistic QA site) "what should I do with this repo ?" wil not yield a straight answer.