# Using shallow clone to get rid of bad commits but still honor outstanding branches; and ideally avoid force push to remote

Tags: git, version-control

we have this situation:

```
                 G
                /
               /
--A---B---C---D---E---F
           \
            \
             H
```

I want to remove commits A-E because they contain sensitive info (or in many cases for other people, very large files that we don't want to be downloaded all the time by git).

*But* I still want G and H to be able to be merged with F.

Is this possible? Perhaps using a shallow clone with a force push, or with rebase or squash?

The only other way I know is to delete the .git folder, create a new repo and force push, but then G and H would definitely not be mergeable (unless we wanted to mess with divergent branch histories and orphans or something?)

Comment: I think the best you can do is either first cherry-pick `H` and `G` onto `A^`, then rewrite `A-F` into `F'` as normal, or rewrite `A-F` into `A',F'` first and then cherry pick onto `A'`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume a slightly more general setup, with several commits in the off-branching branches, and specific branch names:

```
                     G1--G2--...--GN (branch-2)
                    /
                   /
--A^--A---B---C---D---E---F (master)
               \
                \
                 H1--H2--...--HN (branch-1)
```

Note that everywhere below `X'` denotes the ID of a commit that was derived from the commit `X`. In all the commands, substitute it with a commit ID (without the single-quote).

#### Option 1: Rebase onto `A^`

Since you intend to *delete* `A-E`, it is likely that the changes in `A-D` do not affect the changes introduced in branches `branch-1` and `branch-2`. If that is the case, you can simply remove `A-D` from their histories, then rewrite-away `A-E` like normal.

```
$ git switch branch-1
$ git rebase -i A^  # selectively drop A-C

$ git switch branch-2
$ git rebase -i A^  # selectively drop A-D

$ git switch master
$ git rebase -i A^  # selectively drop A-E
```

which will leave you with the history

```
           
     G1'--G2'--...--GN' (branch-2)
    /
   /
--A^---F' (master)
   \
    \
     H1'--H2'--...--HN' (branch-1)
```

#### Option 2: Cherry picking

This is a more general approach that will work regardless of whether you need to keep some changes from `A-E`.

Start by [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1338728/11082165)/[modifying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1186535/11082165) `A-E` to produce some new history `A'-F'`.

Next, to restore the branches `branch-1` and `branch-2`, create new branches off whatever revisions are applicable from `A'-F'`, and then cherry pick the commits `H1..HN` and `G1..GN`:

```
$ git switch -c new-branch-1 C'
$ git cherry-pick H1..HN

$ git switch -c new-branch-2 D'
$ git cherry-pick G1..GN
```

This will produce the new history

```
                    G1'--G2'--...--GN' (new-branch-2)
                   /
                  /
--A'---B'---C'---D'---E'---F' (master)
             \
              \
               H1'--H2'--...--HN' (new-branch-1)
```

Comment: thanks, I am trying to follow the logic. Would this allow us to avoid a force push to the remote(s)?

Comment: @AlexanderMills You would still need to force push, since the remote ref won't be an ancestor of the local ref. If you want to avoid a force-push, you can use new branch names or delete the remote refs first.