# How to rebase after git commit --amend?

Tags: git

I have branch `dev` with 3 commits `ABCD0001` -> `EFGH0001` -> `IJKL0001`

Here are the commands I executed:

1. `git checkout ABCD0001`
2. Do some changes
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit --amend` and get new commit hash `ABCD0002`

I want to keep the change to the whole branch, make the branch something like:

`ABCD0002` -> X -> Y

Which X is basically `EFGH0001` base on `ABCD0002`

Which Y is basically `IJKL0001` base on X

Could someone please guide me on how to do this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Bascally, you can either 1) cherry-pick X then Y by their hashes, then finally moving the `dev` ref where your (currently detached) `HEAD` points to after the cherry-picks, or 2) checkout `dev` then rebase on `ABCD0002`.

Comment: I would advice to adjust the charts so that the arrows are in the opposite direction.... in `git`, child commits point to parents, not the other way around.

Comment: The easy way, to complete @RomainValeri's comment is to do: `git rebase --onto ABCD0002 ABCD0001 dev`  and it will take care of rebasing and adjusting the position of the `dev` branch in a single shot.

Comment: The easy way *would have been* if you had started with `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and then edited the instruction sheet to read `edit ABCD0001` instead of `pick ABCD0001`. After saving and exiting the editor, you would have then got the opportunity to do the amendment. Then a final `git rebase --continue` would have completed what you now have to do manually.

Comment: The time to think about what to do was _before_ you got yourself into a detached head situation unnecessarily. What you did is _not_ the best way to amend an "old" commit. Next time, _search_. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-do-i-modify-a-specific-commit