# git: fixup automatically the commit a changed line belongs to

Tags: git

Imagine making a typo in a comment or something trivially similar:

```
- // Do thigns
+ // Do things
```

Now, by doing `git blame @ -- file` you see the commit the line was originally added in:

```
decafbad ... // Do thigns
```

You can make the fixup to that line manually by running: `git commit --fixup decafbad`.

Is there any way to automate this `git blame @ -- file |grep thigns`, `git commit --fixup decafbad` cycle?

Comment: Maybe using a similar idea as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33222562/6309?

Comment: @VonC: seems a bit wonky and uses the last commit the file was modified in, which is often not the case when I'm doing fixups.

Answer (score 1):

with `bash` I wrote a small script to obtain this. This script supposes that you only made one fixup change, so it looks only at the first file modified and the first line that was changed:

```
file=$(git diff | sed -n "s/.* a\/\(.*\) \+\+\+.*/\1/p")
line_removed=$(git diff | tail -n +6 | sed -n "s/^-\(.*\)/\1/p")
hash=$(git blame HEAD $file | grep $line_removed | awk "{print \$1}")
git commit -a --fixup $hash
```

if you put this code inside `/usr/bin/git-auto-fixup` (and make it executable), then you can invoke it like this: `git auto-fixup`

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this workflow using a tool like `git-autofixup` from
Jordan Torbiak.

https://github.com/torbiak/git-autofixup

The `git-autofixup` script from above is smarter than the short bash script suggested by Chris Maes in another answer, as it can create multiple commits from independent hunks (changes) and you can even leave work-in-progress uncommitted by first staging the hunks you would like to commit to the index.

Refer to the Git repository for more information and documentation. The discussion in https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3053#issuecomment-410475533 tracks how that script was integrated with Magit, a Git interface for Emacs.