# Temporarily revert to previous commit, make changes, keep the changes and come back to latest commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

As you can tell from the title, the reason I'm needing to make my own question about this is I can't quite get the terminology correct to properly search.

I'm working with Git in Sourcetree, and say I have a history of commits

```
F <- I am here
E
D
C
B
A
```

What I need to do is restore the working environment to commit C. Then, make some changes and additions to the code (to export a quick patch for the app being developed) and then to return back to F, preserving the changes I made.

I feel like I need to **Checkout** C, but am unsure at the moment, and would prefer not to bork everything until I get a better understanding.

**Edit: I was thinking I could Checkout C, make changes. Stash the changes. Go back to F. And then apply/commit the stash?**

Comment: You want to do an interactive rebase. You'll find plenty of answers on here using that as a search term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily fixup a past commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103589/how-can-i-easily-fixup-a-past-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. commit all your current changes in 'F'.
2. create a branch from  'C': `git checkout C -b C-branch`.
3. do whatever you need  and commit your changes: `git commit`
4. check out 'F' again: `git checkout F`
5. merge with the C-branch: `git merge C-branch`