# Git rebase is not working by conflicting in current branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

I am trying to run git rebase -i  but git rebase is failed to work on my console. Here I am giving the reason and talking about my errors?

```
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
        git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
        rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

I am very concerned about would it will be wise to run rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge" to remove the git merge and run git rebase -i again.

Comment: If you are certain that you don't have another rebase running, or, if you do, you don't want that work, then there should be no fear in trying both options suggested to you by Git.

Comment: If you want to abort the rebase : try `git rebase --abort` first.

Comment: Actually, I want to delete my older commits that's why I was using git rebase -i

Comment: I had already try this but run git rebase --abort and then run git rebase -i <commit>

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/3828861/4311135

Answer (score -1):

I had already try this but run git rebase --abort and then run git rebase -i  but this is showing in my console and no keywords are working when I try to type and I am using ubuntu. Actually, I want to delete my older commits when I create a branch I had to merge my main branch in there and start working on it but after when I create a new pull request I saw all my older commits were on that branch. And I want to delete all older commits.

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 
pick ba518d16 all linting correction done                     
pick 1aaec497 correction and circleci linting done            
pick 469909fc fixing linting correction done                  
pick 0c34faa1 removing unrelated changed 1                    
pick 97d21359 removing unrelated change: 1                    
pick dee76486 issue fixing: 2                                 
pick 05d1ce18 fixing and correction : 2                       
pick a7b4691b issues correction : 2                           
pick 73251bfe correction: 3                                   
pick 50735a79 correction: 6 and linting fixing                
pick 995ab4e5 trackthread file correction done                
pick c9f13687 receive profile file correction 
pick 30c14bd7 correction: 1                                   
pick 9ba82155 correction: 2                                   
pick 75764831 working with to navigate and zoom by double cli\
cking                                                         
--**-Mg: git-rebase-todo                  (fundamental)----To\
```

Comment: I want to delete my older commits which is 10 days ago