# How can I remove/delete a large file from the commit history in the Git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I accidentally dropped a DVD-rip into a website project, carelessly `git commit -a -m ...`, and, zap, the repository was bloated by 2.2 GB. Next time I made some edits, deleted the video file, and committed everything, but the compressed file was still there in the repository, in history.

I know I can start branches from those commits and rebase one branch onto another. But what should I do to merge the two commits, so that the big file doesn't show in the history and is cleaned in the garbage collection procedure?

Comment: Related: [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-unwanted-file-from-git-repository-history).

Comment: Note that if your large file is in a subdir you'll need to specify the full relative path.

Comment: Also related https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history

Comment: Many answers below tout BFG as easier than `git filter-branch`, but I found the opposite to be true.

Comment: Please have also a look at my answer which uses ```git filter-repo```. You should not longer use ```git filter-branch``` as it is very slow and often difficult to use. ```git filter-repo``` is around 100 times faster.

Comment: The answers have lots of good info for complex situations.  For the simple case where you added the file then removed it in the very next commit, you could just squash those two commits together.

Comment: Wild that so many answers are concerned about speed. How often are you screwing your repo history that you need to care about efficiency in this operation??

Comment: After my 10th time going through this the right answer is git should just refuse to checkin these files rather than create all this turmoil.

Comment: I came here after googling how to block such Git pushes in the first place. I asked about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588572/can-i-configure-github-to-block-large-files).

Comment: As suggested in other comments, the go to option nowadays is to use `git filter-repo`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/86072)

Comment: [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)'s an updated link for the "[removing sensitive data](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)" link originally posted by @MBO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### New answer that works in 2022

Do not use:

```
git filter-branch
```

This command might not change the remote repository after pushing. If you clone after using it, you will see that nothing has changed and the repository still has a large size. It seems this command is old now. For example, if you use the steps in  https://github.com/18F/C2/issues/439, this won't work.

**The Solution**

This solution is based on using:

```
git filter-repo
```

Steps:

(1) Find the largest files in .git (change 10 to whatever number of files you want to display):

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep -f <(git verify-pack -v  .git/objects/pack/*.idx| sort -k 3 -n | cut -f 1 -d " " | tail -10)
```

(2) Start filtering these large files by passing the path&name of the file you would like to remove:

```
 git filter-repo --path-glob '../../src/../..' --invert-paths --force
```

Or use the extension of the file, e.g., to filter all *.zip* files:

```
 git filter-repo --path-glob '*.zip' --invert-paths --force
```

Or, e.g., to filter all .a library files:

```
 git filter-repo --path-glob '*.a' --invert-paths --force
```

or
whatever you find in step 1.

(3)

```
 git remote add origin git@github.com:.../...git
```

(4)

```
git push --all --force

git push --tags --force
```

Done!!!

Comment: What does "Strat" mean in item 2).  What are you doing in that step.  Please explain what 3 is doing, especially ".../...git".  I already have repo with a remote.  What is all of the .../ about?

Comment: I like this solution. Poster should've mentioned "filter-repo" isn't a native git command, you have to install a python script: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: Is this a message from the future? Please tell me what life is like in 20222. I can't believe you are still using git.

Comment: Step 1 could be done with `git filter-repo --analyze`.

Comment: I get "git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."  git version 2.25.1

Comment: @SanjayManohar github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Answer (score 846):

Use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch`, specifically designed for removing unwanted files from Git history.

Carefully follow the [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage). The core part is just this:

```
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M my-repo.git
```

Any files over 100 MB in size (that aren't in your *latest* commit) will be removed from your Git repository's history. You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

After pruning, we can force push to the remote repo*

```
git push --force
```

***Note***: cannot force push a protect branch on GitHub

The BFG is typically at least [10-50](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsR1d5Zpes8HdER3VGU1a3dOcmVHMmtzT2dsS2xNenc#gid=0) times faster than running `git-filter-branch`, and generally easier to use.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: @Roberto: I followed the usage instructions on the site doing a clone --mirror. When it came time to push the repo, it failed stating that I needed to pull first. I'm pretty sure there have been no commits between the time I clone and push back. If I pull, git complains that it needs a working tree inside my-repo.git. Any suggestions?

Comment: @tony It's worth repeating the entire cloning & clearing procedure to see if the message asking you to pull re-occurs, but it's almost certainly because your remote server is configured to reject non-fast-forward updates (ie, it's configured to stop you from losing history - which is exactly what you want to do). You need to get that setting changed on the remote, or failing that, push the updated repo history to a brand new blank repo.

Comment: @RobertoTyley Thanks. I have tried it 3 different times and all resulted with the same message. So I'm also thinking that you're right about the remote server being configured to reject the non-fast-forward updates. I'll consider just pushing the updated repo to a brand new repo. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertoTyley Perfect, you save my time, thanks very much. By the way, maybe should do `git push --force` after your steps, otherwise the remote repo still not changed.

Comment: +1 to adding `git push  --force`.  Also worth noting:  force pushes may not be allowed by the remote (gitlab.com doesn't, by default.  Had to "unprotect" the branch).

Comment: Instead of `--strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M` you can also use `-b 100M` according to help.

Comment: Not sure if BFG automatically deletes the reflog references... if not, you still need to run: `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=all` as described by @Greg Bacon in his answer here.  If there are still reflog entries, the data will not be removed by `git gc`, even with `aggressive` (apparently there are limits to its aggressiveness)

Comment: Tip: If you run bfg.jar with the file declared in .gitignore, it won't be removed.

Comment: @Tony BFG must rewrite history to do what it does, essentially creating a whole new commit tree.  This by definition mean that the commits get new sha1 hashes which is why the force push is needed, as the parent is no longer what the server expects.  This is usually a _GOOD_ thing, but in this particular case we know better.

Comment: @RobertoTyley: I got a general question, is BFG equally functional on Windows as much as on Linux/Mac?

Comment: @WaqasShah : yes, it runs on any platform that has Java 7 or above installed. You can download Java for Windows here: https://www.java.com/en/download/

Comment: BFG worked an absolute charm for me. Brought a 517mb repo down to 38 Mb in just a few minutes. Nothing else worked for me prior to finding this answer.

Comment: Undocumented issue (mostly) when given a "is repo packed" error. Use `git gc` on the target repo, then re-execute whatever it was you were doing with BFG. Once that was sorted worked pretty well. Could use more explicit documentation, but then I'm not the quickest learner ;p

Comment: How do you install that stuff? `brew install bfg` gives me
`Warning: bfg 1.12.15 is already installed` ok:
`$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M myrepo.git` I get:
`Error: Unable to access jarfile bfg.jar`

Comment: @DaveRGP Thanks for tip) that issue: `does the repo need to be packed?` definitely must be documented.

Comment: +1 for BFG, I tried the "standard" method using filter-branch and it's FAR slower and in my case it didn't removed all the references to the big files...

Comment: what is myrepo.git?

Comment: In your output, you state that we should run `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

Comment: Is there a way to remove the "Former-commit-id" from all commits?

Comment: Master branch is protected from direct pushes. Will the procedure work as expected from private branch and PR to master?

Comment: Using a free tool that has three lines of output bothers you? Better avoid open-source projects!

Comment: @Roberto Tyley: How do I remove commits which are older than HEAD~5?

Comment: What happens to the commits that happens while we are doing `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` ? because it takes long time... ?

Comment: After the push you probably want to run: `git fetch && git reset origin/master --soft` on existing clones.

Comment: FYI BFG does not work as advertised, and filter-branch does not take that long.  Running BFG 10-30 times with different branches and different configurations takes much longer.

Comment: I tried many other solutions, but BFS is the only one that resulted in a reduction of size "at the remote server side" and maintaining the history at the same time.

Comment: Works really well! My only question before pushing is what will happen with the closed pull requests? Are we going to loose them as the commit hashes will change  ?

Comment: Confirmed April 2021, `git gc --prune=now --aggressive` still does the trick !

Comment: Does this command work when working with local repo? The problem I have is that I have some large file in my local history and I cannot push to remote, so what would be my repo.git?

Comment: @MA19 Yep, wfm.

Comment: Got an exception right off the bat using this tool: "Cleaning commits:        35% ( 7200/20570)java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".  I couldn't find a way around it.

Answer (score 706):

**NB**: Since this answer was written, `git filter-branch` has been deprecated and it no longer supported. See [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for more information.

---

What you want to do is highly disruptive if you have published history to other developers. See [“Recovering From Upstream Rebase” in the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) for the necessary steps after repairing your history.

You have at least two options: [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) and an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---interactive), both explained below.

### Using `git filter-branch`

I had a similar problem with bulky binary test data from a Subversion import and wrote about [removing data from a git repository](http://blog.gbacon.com/2009/08/git-shrinking-subversion-import.html).

Say your git history is:

```
$ git lola --name-status
* f772d66 (HEAD, master) Login page
| A     login.html
* cb14efd Remove DVD-rip
| D     oops.iso
* ce36c98 Careless
| A     oops.iso
| A     other.html
* 5af4522 Admin page
| A     admin.html
* e738b63 Index
  A     index.html
```

Note that [`git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) is a non-standard but highly useful alias. (See the addendum at the end of this answer for details.) The `--name-status` switch to `git log` shows tree modifications associated with each commit.

In the “Careless” commit (whose SHA1 object name is ce36c98) the file `oops.iso` is the DVD-rip added by accident and removed in the next commit, cb14efd. Using the technique described in the aforementioned blog post, the command to execute is:

```bash
git filter-branch --prune-empty -d /dev/shm/scratch \
  --index-filter "git rm --cached -f --ignore-unmatch oops.iso" \
  --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Options:

- `--prune-empty` removes commits that become empty (*i.e.*, do not change the tree) as a result of the filter operation. In the typical case, this option produces a cleaner history.
- `-d` names a temporary directory that does not yet exist to use for building the filtered history. If you are running on a modern Linux distribution, specifying a [tree in `/dev/shm` will result in faster execution](https://superuser.com/q/45342/20872).
- `--index-filter` is the main event and runs against the index at each step in the history. You want to remove `oops.iso` wherever it is found, but it isn’t present in all commits. The command `git rm --cached -f --ignore-unmatch oops.iso` deletes the DVD-rip when it is present and does not fail otherwise.
- `--tag-name-filter` describes how to rewrite tag names. A filter of `cat` is the identity operation. Your repository, like the sample above, may not have any tags, but I included this option for full generality.
- `--` specifies the end of options to `git filter-branch`
- `--all` following `--` is shorthand for all refs. Your repository, like the sample above, may have only one ref (master), but I included this option for full generality.

After some churning, the history is now:

```
$ git lola --name-status
* 8e0a11c (HEAD, master) Login page
| A     login.html
* e45ac59 Careless
| A     other.html
|
| * f772d66 (refs/original/refs/heads/master) Login page
| | A   login.html
| * cb14efd Remove DVD-rip
| | D   oops.iso
| * ce36c98 Careless
|/  A   oops.iso
|   A   other.html
|
* 5af4522 Admin page
| A     admin.html
* e738b63 Index
  A     index.html
```

Notice that the new “Careless” commit adds only `other.html` and that the “Remove DVD-rip” commit is no longer on the master branch. The branch labeled `refs/original/refs/heads/master` contains your original commits in case you made a mistake. To remove it, follow the steps in [“Checklist for Shrinking a Repository.”](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository)

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

For a simpler alternative, clone the repository to discard the unwanted bits.

```
$ cd ~/src
$ mv repo repo.old
$ git clone file:///home/user/src/repo.old repo
```

Using a `file:///...` clone URL copies objects rather than creating hardlinks only.

Now your history is:

```
$ git lola --name-status
* 8e0a11c (HEAD, master) Login page
| A     login.html
* e45ac59 Careless
| A     other.html
* 5af4522 Admin page
| A     admin.html
* e738b63 Index
  A     index.html
```

The SHA1 object names for the first two commits (“Index” and “Admin page”) stayed the same because the filter operation did not modify those commits. “Careless” lost `oops.iso` and “Login page” got a new parent, so their SHA1s *did* change.

### Interactive rebase

With a history of:

```
$ git lola --name-status
* f772d66 (HEAD, master) Login page
| A     login.html
* cb14efd Remove DVD-rip
| D     oops.iso
* ce36c98 Careless
| A     oops.iso
| A     other.html
* 5af4522 Admin page
| A     admin.html
* e738b63 Index
  A     index.html
```

you want to remove `oops.iso` from “Careless” as though you never added it, and then “Remove DVD-rip” is useless to you. Thus, our plan going into an interactive rebase is to keep “Admin page,” edit “Careless,” and discard “Remove DVD-rip.”

Running `$ git rebase -i 5af4522` starts an editor with the following contents.

```
pick ce36c98 Careless
pick cb14efd Remove DVD-rip
pick f772d66 Login page

# Rebase 5af4522..f772d66 onto 5af4522
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Executing our plan, we modify it to

```
edit ce36c98 Careless
pick f772d66 Login page

# Rebase 5af4522..f772d66 onto 5af4522
# ...
```

That is, we delete the line with “Remove DVD-rip” and change the operation on “Careless” to be `edit` rather than `pick`.

Save-quitting the editor drops us at a command prompt with the following message.

```
Stopped at ce36c98... Careless
You can amend the commit now, with

        git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

        git rebase --continue
```

As the message tells us, we are on the “Careless” commit we want to edit, so we run two commands.

```
$ git rm --cached oops.iso
$ git commit --amend -C HEAD
$ git rebase --continue
```

The first removes the offending file from the index. The second modifies or amends “Careless” to be the updated index and `-C HEAD` instructs git to reuse the old commit message. Finally, `git rebase --continue` goes ahead with the rest of the rebase operation.

This gives a history of:

```
$ git lola --name-status
* 93174be (HEAD, master) Login page
| A     login.html
* a570198 Careless
| A     other.html
* 5af4522 Admin page
| A     admin.html
* e738b63 Index
  A     index.html
```

which is what you want.

### Addendum: Enable `git lola` via `~/.gitconfig`

[Quoting Conrad Parker](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html):

> The best tip I learned at Scott Chacon’s talk at linux.conf.au 2010, Git Wrangling - Advanced Tips and Tricks was this alias:

> ```
> lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
> ```

> This provides a really nice graph of your tree, showing the branch structure of merges etc. Of course there are really nice GUI tools for showing such graphs, but the advantage of `git lol` is that it works on a console or over `ssh`, so it is useful for remote development, or native development on an embedded board …

> So, just copy the following into `~/.gitconfig` for your full color `git lola` action:
>
> ```
> [alias]
>         lol = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
>         lola = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
> [color]
>         branch = auto
>         diff = auto
>         interactive = auto
>         status = auto
> ```

Comment: Why i can't push when using git filter-branch, failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:product/myproject.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.

Comment: Add the `-f` (or `--force`) option to your `git push` command: “Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.”

Comment: This is a wonderfully thorough answer explaining the use of git-filter-branch to remove unwanted large files from history, but it's worth noting that since Greg wrote his answer, The BFG Repo-Cleaner has been released, which is often faster and easier to use - see my answer for details.

Comment: After I do either of the procedures above, the remote repository (on GitHub) does NOT delete the large file. Only the local does. I force push and nada.  What am I missing?

Comment: this also works on dirs. `... "git rm --cached -rf --ignore-unmatch path/to/dir"...`

Comment: I can't just delete "pick cb14efd Remove DVD-rip" line, cause in "Remove DVD-rip" commit I did some other stuff. (in Interactive Rebase solution)

Comment: @Ehsan In your case, mark both commits with `edit` and clean up by hand in the shell.

Comment: hiks, can anyone explain more simple step.. this is to confusing to me.. :(

Comment: @AaA See the link to the [blog post by Conrad Parker with the definition of `git lola`](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html), also linked in the answer.

Comment: @GregBacon, I'm sorry, my comment is missing and I don't even remember what was the question

Comment: @AaA My recollection is you asked about the definitions of `git lol` and `git lola`.

Comment: I removed the `refs/original/refs/heads/master` branch created after the `filter-branch` using the backup+`git clone` steps and the remotes of the original repo were lost in the new repo, having the original repo itself as the new remote instead. I would perhaps indicate it for completeness

Comment: Your solution works when I apply two times, second one after the `git push --all --force` , is it normal?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answered. Solved the issue for me.

Comment: The interactive rebase approach is the best one, i think.
Self explaining and full control without third-party tools.
Just `git rm --cached file.ext` did not working for me and asked for forcing.
But in my case (just want to move the file to LFS) it also worked by just add an suitable `.gitattributes` file in the same commit.

Answer (score 319):

**NB**: Since this answer was written, `git filter-branch` has been deprecated and it no longer supported. See [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for more information.

---

Why not use this simple but powerful command?

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f DVD-rip' HEAD
```

The `--tree-filter` option runs the specified command after each checkout of the project and then recommits the results. In this case, you remove a file called DVD-rip from every snapshot, whether it exists or not.

If you know which commit introduced the huge file (say 35dsa2), you can replace HEAD with 35dsa2..HEAD to avoid rewriting too much history, thus avoiding diverging commits if you haven't pushed yet. This comment courtesy of @alpha_989 seems too important to leave out here.

See [this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch).

Comment: Much better than bfg. I was unable to clean file from a git with bfg, but this command helped

Comment: This is great. Just a note for others that you'll have to do this per branch if the large file is in multiple branches.

Comment: This worked for me on a local commit that I couldn't upload to GitHub. And it seemed simpler than the other solutions.

Comment: All this does for me is create a huge `.git-rewrite` directory while keeping the removed files in the repo.

Comment: If you know the `commit` where you put the file in (say `35dsa2`), you can replace `HEAD` with `35dsa2..HEAD`. `tree-filter` is much slower than `index-filter` that way it wont try to checkout all the commits and rewrite them. if you use HEAD, it will try to do that.

Comment: I tried this and now have "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 49 and 44 different commits each, respectively."

Comment: After running the above command, you then have to run `git push --all --force` to get remote's history to match the amended version you have now created locally (@stevec)

Comment: does this keep the latest version of the file?

Comment: This worked great for me! @JoãoPimentelFerreira - for me, it kept the latest version of the file, plus allowed me to reconcile the local commits that hadn't been pushed to the remote yet. I backed everything up just in case and would recommend doing the same.

Answer (score 136):

### 100 times faster than git filter-branch and easier to use

There are very good answers in this thread, but meanwhile many of them are outdated. Using `git-filter-branch` is no longer recommended, because it is difficult to use and awfully slow on big repositories with many commits.

`git-filter-repo` is much faster and easier to use.

`git-filter-repo` is a Python script, available at github: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo . When installed it looks like a regular git command and can be called by `git filter-repo`.

You need only one file: the Python3 script git-filter-repo. Copy it to a path that is included in the PATH variable. On Windows you may have to change the first line of the script (refer INSTALL.md). You need Python3 installed installed on your system, but this is not a big deal.

First you can run

```
git filter-repo --analyze
```

This helps you to determine what to do next.

You can delete your DVD-rip file everywhere:

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path DVD-rip
```

Filter-repo is really fast. A task that took around 9 hours on my computer by filter-branch, was completed in 4 minutes by filter-repo. You can do many more nice things with filter-repo. Refer to the documentation for that.

**Warning:** Do this on a copy of your repository. Many actions of filter-repo cannot be undone. filter-repo will change the commit hashes of all modified commits (of course) and all their descendants down to the last commits!

Comment: How do I submit the applied changes (on my local repository) to a remote repository? Or this is not possible, and I should clone the amended repo to a new one?

Comment: @diman82: Best would be to make a new empty repository, set the remote repository from your cloned repo to that and push. This is common to all these answers here: You will get many new commit hashes. This is unavoidable because the commit hashes guarantee for the content and the history of a repo. The alternative way is dangerous, you could make a force push and then run gc to get rid of the files. But do not do this unless you have tested very well and you are aware of all the consequences !

Comment: I've already pushed (with --force option), worked well (to a cloned repository, as a precaution).

Comment: `git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M` worked much better on my end

Comment: This worked well for me. filter-repo has good documentation for more advanced cases but in mine, I just needed to get rid of big file I accidentally committed. In my case, it worked fine to duplicate the project dir, run the command in the new version, re-add the remote and push (no strictly fresh clone).

Comment: this should be the accepted answer now. Worked amazingly well.

Comment: Because my commits with large files had not been pushed yet, I managed to keep the same repository by using. After making a copy of my local repo, I did:
`git filter-repo --invert-paths --path DVD-rip --force`
which allowed me to remove the file even though it was not a freshly cloned repo. Next, I restored the ability to pull and push as follows: 
`git fetch` and 
`git push --set-upstream main main`.

Answer (score 116):

After trying virtually every answer in SO, I finally found this gem that quickly removed and deleted the large files in my repository and allowed me to sync again: http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4027/how-to-delete-files-permanently-from-your-local-and-remote-git-repositories

CD to your local working folder and run the following command:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch FOLDERNAME" -- --all
```

replace FOLDERNAME with the file or folder you wish to remove from the given git repository.

Once this is done run the following commands to clean up the local repository:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Now push all the changes to the remote repository:

```
git push --all --force
```

This will clean up the remote repository.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Gets rid of a specific folder (in my case, one that contained files too large or a Github repo) on the repository, but keeps it on the local file system in case it exists.

Comment: Worked for me! no history is left which is potentially confusing (if someone where to clone right now), make sure you have a plan to update any broken links, dependencies, etc

Comment: I tried the `filter-branch` methods described in the other answers, but they didn't work. After filtering, I still got file size too big error when pushing to GitHub. This solution worked, most likely because it removed the big file from ALL occurrences in ALL branches.

Comment: May also need `git push origin --tags --force` to remove large files from the remote in tagged releases.

Comment: This is great. Want to add, for the last command, if you have a very large repo with many commits, instead of doing `--all`, read this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51468389) to split up pushes (note, replace *git push* with *git push -f*). I had to do this because the pack size exceeded 2 GB trying to push everything at once.

And comment two - *back up everything*!

Comment: I guess it's only me that didn't realize this command will also nuke the file from the project itself, not just the git repo. Certainly worked though!

Comment: Worked for me! One question though, why is `git reflog expire` required?

Comment: why is git reflog expire required?

Comment: Fyi if you are Windows you can do:
`rmdir /s /q .git\refs\original`   
 in place of  `rm -rf .git/refs/original`

Answer (score 45):

These commands worked in my case:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch oops.iso' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

It is little different from the previous versions.

For those who need to push this to GitHub/Bitbucket (I only tested this with Bitbucket):

```
# WARNING!!!
# This will rewrite completely your Bitbucket refs
# will delete all branches that you didn't have in your local

git push --all --prune --force

# Once you pushed, all your teammates need to clone repository again
# git pull will not work
```

Comment: How is it different from above, why is it better?

Comment: For some reason mkljun version is not reduced git space in my case, I already had removed the files from index by using `git rm --cached files`. The Greg Bacon's proposition is more complete, and quite the same to this mine, but he missed the --force index for cases when you are using filter-branch for multiple times, and he wrote so much info, that my version is like resume of it.

Comment: This really helped but I needed to use the `-f` option not just `-rf` here `git rm --cached -rf --ignore-unmatch oops.iso` instead of `git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch oops.iso` as per @lfender6445 below

Answer (score 20):

According to GitHub [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#using-filter-branch), just follow these steps:

1. Get rid of the large file

   *Option 1: You don't want to keep the large file:*

   ```
   rm path/to/your/large/file        # Delete the large file
   ```

   *Option 2: You want to keep the large file into an untracked directory*

   ```
   mkdir large_files                       # Create directory large_files
   touch .gitignore                        # Create .gitignore file if needed
   '/large_files/' >> .gitignore           # Untrack directory large_files
   mv path/to/your/large/file large_files/ # Move the large file into the untracked directory
   ```
2. Save your changes

   ```
   git add path/to/your/large/file   # Add the deletion to the index
   git commit -m 'delete large file' # Commit the deletion
   ```
3. Remove the large file from all commits

   ```
   git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
     "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/your/large/file" \
     --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
   git push <remote> <branch>
   ```

Comment: can you elaborate on how the "remove the large file from all commits" step worked, that was amazing!

Comment: Thanks @clayg. I don't understand deeply the `git filter-branch` command, as I wrote, I just followed the GitHub documentation. What I know is that this command browses through your `.git` folder and find all tracks of the given file and removes it from the history.

Comment: @KevinR. you have to force push, isnt it?

Comment: That is correct @Exploring

Comment: Thank you, damn python programmers and checking in binary files.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this with a Bitbucket account, where I had accidentally stored ginormous **.jpa* backups of my site.

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch MY-BIG-DIRECTORY-OR-FILE' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Replace `MY-BIG-DIRECTORY` with the folder in question to completely rewrite your history (*including tags*).

Source: *[Finding and Purging Big Files From Git History](https://web.archive.org/web/20170727144429/http://naleid.com:80/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history/)*

Comment: This response helped me, except the script in the answer has a slight issue and it doesn't search in all branches form me. But the command in the link did it perfectly.

Comment: Add `-f` after `git filter-branch`, if need to overwrite previous backup

Answer (score 10):

Just note that these_ commands can be very destructive. If more people are working on the repository they'll all have to pull the new tree. The three middle commands are not necessary if your goal is *not* to reduce the size. Because the filter branch creates a backup of the removed file and it can stay there for a long time.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch YOURFILENAME" HEAD
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --all
git gc --aggressive --prune
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: Do NOT run these commands unless you want to create immense pain for yourself. It deleted a lot of my original source code files. I assumed it would purge some large files from my commit history in GIT (as per the original question), however, I think this command is designed to permanently purge files from your original source code tree (big difference!). My system: Windows, VS2012, Git Source Control Provider.

Comment: I used this command: `git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch oops.iso' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` instead of first one from your code

Comment: @mkljun, please at least remove "git push origin master --force"! First of all it is not related to the original question - author didn't ask how to edit commits and push changes to some repository. And second - this is dangerous, you really can delete a lot of files and push changes to remote repository without first check what was deleted is not a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f path/to/file' HEAD` 
worked pretty well for me, although I ran into the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6403601/97443), which I solved by following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404368/97443).

The pro-git book has an entire chapter on [rewriting history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) - have a look at the [`filter-branch`/Removing a File from Every Commit](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch) section.

Answer (score 8):

If you know your commit was recent instead of going through the entire tree do the following:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm LARGE_FILE.zip' HEAD~10..HEAD`

Answer (score 5):

I basically did what was on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11032521/1286423

(for history, I'll copy-paste it here)

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch YOURFILENAME" HEAD
$ rm -rf .git/refs/original/ 
$ git reflog expire --all 
$ git gc --aggressive --prune
$ git push origin master --force
```

It didn't work, because I like to rename and move things a lot. So some big file were in folders that have been renamed, and I think the gc couldn't delete the reference to those files because of reference in `tree` objects pointing to those file.
My ultimate solution to really kill it was to:

```
# First, apply what's in the answer linked in the front
# and before doing the gc --prune --aggressive, do:

# Go back at the origin of the repository
git checkout -b newinit <sha1 of first commit>
# Create a parallel initial commit
git commit --amend
# go back on the master branch that has big file
# still referenced in history, even though 
# we thought we removed them.
git checkout master
# rebase on the newinit created earlier. By reapply patches,
# it will really forget about the references to hidden big files.
git rebase newinit

# Do the previous part (checkout + rebase) for each branch
# still connected to the original initial commit, 
# so we remove all the references.

# Remove the .git/logs folder, also containing references
# to commits that could make git gc not remove them.
rm -rf .git/logs/

# Then you can do a garbage collection,
# and the hidden files really will get gc'ed
git gc --prune --aggressive
```

My repo (the `.git`) changed from 32MB to 388KB, that even filter-branch couldn't clean.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/), it's a UI tool. It has a plugin named "Find large files" which finds lage files in repositories and allow removing them permenently.

Don't use 'git filter-branch' before using this tool, since it won't be able to find files removed by 'filter-branch' (Altough 'filter-branch' does not remove files completely from the repository pack files).

Comment: This method is waaay too slow for large repositories.  It took over an hour to list the large files.  Then when I go to delete files, after an hour it is only 1/3 of the way through processing the first file I want to delete.

Comment: Yes, its slow, but does the work... Do you know anything quicker?

Comment: Haven't used it, but BFG Repo-Cleaner, as per another answer on this page.

Comment: Git Extension is nice and simple. However it uses git filter-branch internally, so deletion is very slow.

Answer (score 3):

`git filter-branch` is a powerful command which you can use it to delete a huge file from the commits history. The file will stay for a while and Git will remove it in the next garbage collection.
Below is the full process from [deleteing files from commit history](https://www.gloomycorner.com/deleting-files-from-git-commit-history/). For safety, below process runs the commands on a new branch first. If the result is what you needed, then reset it back to the branch you actually want to change.

```
# Do it in a new testing branch
$ git checkout -b test

# Remove file-name from every commit on the new branch
# --index-filter, rewrite index without checking out
# --cached, remove it from index but not include working tree
# --ignore-unmatch, ignore if files to be removed are absent in a commit
# HEAD, execute the specified command for each commit reached from HEAD by parent link
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file-name' HEAD

# The output is OK, reset it to the prior branch master
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --soft test

# Remove test branch
$ git branch -d test

# Push it with force
$ git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-the-git-repository#comment120810493_61602985) was such a useful comment by @Lucas that I've decided to post it as an answer so that more people see it.

They said to use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) and run the command: `git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M`

If you're struggling to install `git-filter-repo` on Windows (like I was), please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77144148/how-to-install-git-filter-repo-on-windows).

What does this do and how does it work? I don't know. If you do, please leave a comment.

However, afterwards, my commit history remained with all the huge files no longer in the commit history. It worked.

As always, **back up your repo before running this**.

Answer (score 1):

When you run into this problem, `git rm` will not suffice, as git remembers that the file existed once in our history, and thus will keep a reference to it.

To make things worse, rebasing is not easy either, because any references to the blob will prevent git garbage collector from cleaning up the space. This includes remote references and reflog references.

I put together `git forget-blob`, a little script that tries removing all these references, and then uses git filter-branch to rewrite every commit in the branch.

Once your blob is completely unreferenced, `git gc` will get rid of it

The usage is pretty simple `git forget-blob file-to-forget`. You can get more info here

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/18/completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-with-git-forget-blob/

I put this together thanks to the answers from Stack Overflow and some blog entries. Credits to them!

Comment: you should get this in homebrew

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `branch filter` command:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/to/your/file' HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Other than `git filter-branch` (slow but pure git solution) and [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) (easier and very performant), there is also another tool to filter with good performance:

https://github.com/xoofx/git-rocket-filter

From its description:

The purpose of git-rocket-filter is similar to the command `git-filter-branch` while providing the following unique features:

- Fast rewriting of commits and trees (by an order of x10 to x100).
- Built-in support for both white-listing with --keep (keeps files or directories) and black-listing with --remove options.
- Use of .gitignore like pattern for tree-filtering
- Fast and easy C# Scripting for both commit filtering and tree filtering
- Support for scripting in tree-filtering per file/directory pattern
- Automatically prune empty/unchanged commit, including merge commits

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. so with `git rebase -i HEAD~15` I turned the commit which had large file to `edit` mode, then `git rm {relative/path/largeFile}` removed the large file from the commit and did `git rebase --continue`.

Also I added `{relative/path/largeFile} filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text` to `.gitattributes` and did a commit.

Note the `git filter-repo` even though messaged successful didn't work for me. Note I cloned the `git clone https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo.git` in another directory. Then from that directory ran `python git-filter-repo --path  "{large\File\Path}"  --invert-paths`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, `git lfs migrate ...` is preferable. It's simple, fast, easy-to-use, and requires no extra installations. For this task of rewriting git history to move large files to LFS, you'll need the `info` and `import` sub-commands. [docs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.adoc), [tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#migrating-existing-repository-data-to-lfs)

For my work today, the final solution was:

```
git clone [remote_path_to_repo] repo_cleanup
cd repo_cleanup
# Ensure my local checkout is complete..
git lfs fetch all

# Dry run of looking for all file types above 10MB
git lfs migrate info --above=10MB --everything

# Migrate & rewrite local history
git lfs migrate import --above=10MB --everything

# Force-push to overwrite remote history
# This will break compatibility with all existing checkouts!
# Ensure you first coordinate with all other developers to make fresh checkouts.
git push -f --mirror
```

FWIW, I found `git lfs migrate` much more convenient and usable than BFG Repo-Cleaner. I didn't try `filter-branch` because it seemed overly complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Save a backup of your current code in case anything goes wrong during this process.

```bash
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/large_file' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Replace path/to/large_file with the actual path to the large file that you want to remove. This command will rewrite the Git history and remove the large file from all commits.

After running the git filter-branch command, you may see a message that says "Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged" or similar. This indicates that the branch is not updated yet. To update the branch and apply the changes, use:

```bash
git push origin --force --all
```

Answer (score -4):

This works perfectly for me: in Git extensions:

right-click on the selected commit:

Reset current branch to here:

Hard reset;

It's surprising nobody else is able to give this simple answer.

[image: Reset current branch to here]

[image: Hard reset]

Comment: Worked for me but me mindful this deletes everything after that point

Comment: No-one gave this answer because it does not answer the question. He wants a specific file removed from the history. Your answer nukes everything in the repo after a certain point.

Answer (score -5):

Use:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

It will keep the changes, but remove the commit. Then you can recommit those changes.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the simplest way forward.