# Removing a file after doing git commit, verify its not in the master

Tags: git

I added a 50mb file or so and did a g`it commit`.

I starting doing a :

```
git push origin master
```

But mid-way I cancelled the operation.

1. how can I remove this file from the repo even though I did a git commit (I added it to .gitignore now but its sort of late)
2. how can I see if the file is in the master or not?

I don't want to wipe the entire commit as there are other files I want commited (and not lost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good that you cancelled it.

Remove the giant file.

```
git add -A
git commit --amend -C head
git push origin yourbranch
```

You should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Step one DO NOT PUSH  If you have pushed, report back after doing something drastic.

Decision: Has this been the last commit you made?

Step two--lastcommit: git commit --amend

Step two--oldercommit: read and follow the `man git-rebase` page for the bit about splitting commits

Step three: read and follow the `man git-filter-branch` page for the bit about how to compress your .git directory.  Not critical and it will happen automatically eventually.

Step four: Make a clone from you current repo to double-check that the large file is not sticking around.  Verify by repo size and the absence of the file.

Step five: Push

Comment: I was kidding. But I did forget to undo the down vote. Corrected now.

Comment: The push did not complete. You don't need all those steps.

Answer (score -1):

There's another very similar question here that describes a number of options:

[Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/git-remove-file-accidentally-added-to-the-repository)

The simplest solution would git's [`filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) command.

Comment: filter branch is way too heavy for what he's trying to do.