# How do you completely remove a file on github

Tags: github

I've seen the command needed to remove a file and erase it from the history on git. Is there a way to do this with the github website? If not, it looks like I need to know where the file is to do it with a git command. Where does github store the local repositories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Remove file accidentally added to the repository.how to rewrite the change history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/git-remove-file-accidentally-added-to-the-repository-how-to-rewrite-the-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

To get a local version of the repository, look up the URL from the repo page on Github and clone as explained in the link above.