# using Github but in one push ,add lots of *.jar files about 30M how can delete the *.jar

Tags: git, github

using Github but in one push ,beacuse my uncareful ,I add lots of *.jar files about 30M and push to the repo ,so how can delete the *.jar,the jar make the repo very big

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Answer (score 0):

Before you start: **create a backup**

---

**Scenario 1: You added the jar files in the most recent commit**

Follow these steps:

Delete the jar files:

```
git remove /path/to/file1.jar
git remove /path/to/file2.jar
...
```

Commit using amend

```
git commit --amend
```

Now push --force to overwrite the remote commit. **Attention!** do this only if no others have already pulled the commit:

```
git push --force origin HEAD
```

---

**Scenario 2: You added the jar files not in the most recent commit**

If it was not the recent commit you need to identify the commit where you added the jar files. This can be done using

```
git whatchanged
```

for example.

Then you need to rebase that commit using git rebase. Let's say the commit where you added the jars is `79755c4`

```
git rebase -i 79755c4~1
```

An editor will show up. Replace `pick` by `edit` in the line containing `79755c4` and save.

Now delete the jar files as shown above:

```
git remove /path/to/file1.jar
git remove /path/to/file2.jar
...
```

Commit this changes using amend:

```
git commit --amend
```

Complete the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

And push --force the changes to the remote branch. Again, **Attention!** do this only if no others have already pulled the commit!

```
git push --force origin HEAD
```

That's it.