# Git pushing maximum storage issue

Tags: git, push

I'm trying to push my latest commit but there's a file that is 123MB which surpasses the limit. I tried to add it to my .gitignore but it still keeps attempting to push it and I'm not really sure where to go about with it now. I've been told to try git reset on different commits but I'm not entirely sure when I started tracking it and was wondering if there's a way to completely remove it from being tracked.

I've also tried git rm --cached  but this doesn't seem to be working either for some reason

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history

Comment: not sure if my situation entirely applies to that ^

Comment: How many commits are you trying to push? If you are trying to push just one new commit to remote master branch, the easiest way is probably just to do `git reset --soft origin/master`, then unstage the big file and make a new commit without that file.

Comment: thank you that fixed it!