# How to remove all occurences of a file in index, from all git commits

Tags: git, caching, github, indexing, commit

First time using git here. I accidentally used "git init" without a .gitignore file so I have a bunch of gradle/ and build/ files in my commits. I am using "git ls-tree -r master" to show all files in the index. Instead of checking out every single previous commit and using "git rm --cached " to remove all the unnecessary build and gradle files, how do I remove all occurences of it through all previous commits?

Edit: Is there a way to remove every directory and files in all commits and only keep the src directory?

Comment: Have you googled first? and read through things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history

Comment: Yes, and that link still forces me to manually remove all the files because when I run git rebase, it goes through all the commits and tells me: 
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:


Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Initial Commit
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

Comment: @TommySaechao : Yes, add all the directory and files into `.gitignore`. After that clear the `cache` of it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably really do want the `filter-branch` command rather than `rebase`.  Either way there are several items to be aware of:

- You can't change *any* existing commits, *ever*.
- Therefore, both rebase and filter-branch don't.  Instead, they *copy* commits.  Now you have twice as many commits!  Wait, what?!
- But Git can and will—eventually—remove what it calls *unreferenced* objects (commits and their corresponding files), and you can speed this up in various ways if necessary.

So this is what both rebase and filter-branch do: they copy the commits, and before committing the copy, allow some change(s).  Then, having committed the (slightly different) copies, they move the *references*—the branch and tag names—to the copies.

With that in mind, there are several more items to consider:

- Only filter-branch copies and moves tags, and it only does so if you provide a `--tag-filter`.  (If you have no tags, this does not really matter, obviously.)  And, when filter-branch copies *signed* annotated tags, it ditches their signatures: they become unsigned.  Otherwise it would have to pester you to manually re-sign them all, and filter-branch is designed to be fully automated.
- Because filter-branch is designed to be automated, and because it is designed to be able to run on every commit in a repository, it (a) tends to be slow and (b) has a lot of complicated options meant to speed it up.  If you don't have that many commits, this is not that big a deal.  If you do, it pays off to study how to use its many options to speed it up.
- Because both commands copy commits, if anyone else has a copy of the repository, you're making a bunch of work for them too: they need to switch over to the copies.  If they don't, they can re-introduce all the original commits, and then you are back to having twice as many.

Now you're ready for [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307828/1256452) and its filter-branch answer.  See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/1256452) to a related question as well, though, for instructions on using `--tag-name-filter` and some of the speed-up options.

Note that `git rm -f --cached --ignore-unmatch` works on directory (or "folder") names as well as on plain file names.  The `--tree-filter` (mentioned in other answers on the second-linked page) can be used instead of the `--index-filter`, and it's more convenient for complex operations, but it is *much* slower (exact slowdown varies based on OS, size of repo, SSD vs spinning-media storage, etc., but "about 100x slower" is a good starting estimate) than using the `--index-filter`.