# hg convert abort: '\n' and '\r' disallowed in filenames:

Tags: git, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I'm about to convert my git repo into a hg repo.

The problem is that a few months ago there was a file added named `'favicons/Icon\r'` to the git repo, which is fine for git. The file has been deleted, but since it is in the history I get this output when running the `hg convert` extension:

```
converting...
816 Favicons
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: '\n' and '\r' disallowed in filenames: 'favicons/Icon\r'!
```

Is there a way to work around this or do I have to stay with my git repo? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that path-name is invalid in Mercurial, you must do one or more of the following:

- convert the Git repository with code that skips the "bad" commits and/or files
- convert the Git repository with code that substitutes in a "good" file name instead
- copy the Git repository to an altered Git repository, in which the file name does not appear (removing or altering commits that have that file, a la the prior two methods, but doing it within Git rather than during the conversion to Mercurial).

The first two may be easy to achieve directly using `hg convert`.  For instance, [the documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) mentions the ability to exclude or rename files by file-name.  I have not actually tried this myself, though.

The last is relatively easy since you can use `git filter-branch` to achieve it.  The "relative" in "relatively easy" is *very* relative: `filter-branch` is not particularly easy to use correctly (it's just easier than writing a new Git-to-Mercurial converter).

See [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/1256452) and [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307828/1256452) for examples.  Note that [Greg Bacon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158271/1256452) correctly uses `--tag-name-filter` to adjust tags (this is necessary if you have tags that point into history at or beyond the point at which commits are altered during the copying).

Comment: Thanks! I solved it using the --filemap from the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
echo "exclude \"favicons/Icon"$'\r'$"\"" >> omit
hg convert --filemap omit mygitrepo myhgrepo
```