# .gitignore work wrongly, file disappear when checkout branch

Tags: git

I felt a little bit confused about `.gitignore`. Here's the thing, I developed in `Rails`, and I don't want the `secrets.yml` and `database.yml` to be uploaded into `Github`.

I thought that I only need to edit these two file on the `AWS EC2`, so I add them into `.gitignore`.

Then I run

```
git rm --cached secrets.yml database.yml
```

to clean my `git` track file status.

Therefore, these two file are still in the folder, but they can't be added into `git` track list.

However, I found out when I `checkout` other `branch` and then come back. These two files will disappeared, what happened?

Comment: It's because they're still being tracked in the other branches. You'll probably want to rewrite your history with `git filter-branch` to purge those files.

Comment: So if I update every branch, it will solve this queatio.

Comment: Perhaps, but you should know that it will always be available in history, so if you checkout an older commit, then it will disappear when you switch back to master. Plus if it's publicly available repository, anyone can view it

Comment: Oh, I knew that, I just don't want others edit the file to affect on EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git stores these files for each branch individually. So you could have the same files with different contents on many branches. You can also have the files on one branch and have them removed from another branch (which is probably what you currently have).

In case you already pushed your files to Github, **the secrets are already public and should be changed ASAP. Do not just remove the files, you can never be sure nobody copied them!**

As mentioned in the comments, you can `filter-branch` the files out and force-push the repository, but this would break some things if there are other people who have checked out the repository. I'd rather remove the file from all branches using `git rm --cached` and push the branches to keep a stable history and change the secrets.

You can remove the files automatically from all branches:

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/); do
    git checkout "$branch"
    git rm --cached config/secrets.yml config/database.yml
    git commit -m 'Remove secrets.yml'
done
echo "Remember to git push"
```

---

If you haven't pushed the branches yet, you can filter the files out (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646694/1432545)):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch config/secrets.yml config/database.yml' --all
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is fabulous. Now I am about to change the key.

Answer (score 0):

Filter branch works well but is pretty non intuitive and slow at scale. I.e a lot of commits.

GitHub recommends: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/