# Remove all traces of large files in old git commit history

Tags: git, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history, git-lfs

I'm trying to put a Git project on GitHub but its history contains certain large files. If we try `git push` to GitHub, we are getting an error:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: File .OldFiles/blah1/[file].[ext] is 257.29 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Our first commit(say `commit_1`) was containing a few large files which were removed in one subsequent commit(say `commit_2`) without rewriting the git commit history.

We are using `AFS File System`(may be an extra info) and all the old large files are stored at a specific location in `.OldFiles` directory.
In `commit_2`, we have removed `.OldFiles` with it's contents and also have added `blah1` directory to `.gitignore`, but this is not removing their history within Git.
Unfortunately, we need to keep intact several other commits(literally **n** number of commits!) after `commit_1` & `commit_2`.

I have tested over a clone at local sandbox by creating a duplicate branch from as `commit_1`:

```
git checkout -b fix_branch <commit_1_sha_id>
```

Found that `fix_branch` is still containing large files: `.OldFiles/blah1/[file].[ext]`.

Maybe we need to remove these large files in `OldFiles` & it's respective commit histories to do a successful GitHub push.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history) but we are getting an error at `git rebase`:

```
error: unrecognised input
error: could not build fake ancestor
```

Also have tried [this](https://gist.github.com/wrburgess/3711050) but failed:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch [project]/.OldFiles/blah1/[file].[ext]' \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

I'm not sure whether we can use git [cherry-pick](https://docs.acquia.com/article/removing-large-files-git-without-losing-history) as we can not discard all files in `commit_1` but only these large files.

Is it possible to remove all large files traces by rewriting git history and by editing the commits by using `git filter-branch` and `git rebase -i`?

P.S. We do not have `lfs` or `bfg` installed in our project space.

A li'l help will be much appreciated to this newbie! :)

Comment: I would go back to the first commit, remove the file, amend it and cherry-pick whatever was on top of this branch if the layout of the branch is almost-linear. If the layout is more complex then i think you'll have to use filter-branch to correct it.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository and friends.  In what way did the `filter-branch` operation fail?

Comment: @Edmundo, I am not sure how `cherry-pick` may help us. We already have done several commits after `commit_1` and specifically for `commit_1` we need to discard only the large file and keep the other files intact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: That's what I mean. If the branch is rather _linear_, this could be done:
```git checkout commit_1; git rm whateverfile; git commit --amend --no-edit; git cherry-pick commit_1..branch-to-fix;```. Given that on commit_2 (which is the first revision that would be cherry-picked) removed the file and you have already done it in the amended revision, you might get a tree conflict (not completely sure, though).

Comment: Oh... just noticed I asked to checkout commit_1... it would have to be like this: ```git checkout --detach commit_1;``` everything else is ok

Comment: You say your attempt to use `filter-branch` failed, but you do not say *how* it failed. Your example shows pointless backslash-space sequences though, so I suspect you typo'd something.

Comment: @torek, Have tried the following: 
`git checkout -b remove_lfs_fix <commit_1_sha_id>;`

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter \ 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch [project]/.OldFiles/blah1' \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all;`
**OUTPUT: fatal: bad revision ' --prune-empty'**; 

`git filter-branch --index-filter \ 'git update-index --remove [project]/.OldFiles/blah1/[file].[ext]' <commit_1_sha_id>..HEAD;`
**OUTPUT: Found nothing to rewrite**;

Comment: It looks like you are cutting and pasting without understanding: those backslashes are in the other answer mainly for display purposes, they are not meant for you to enter unless you enter the corresponding newlines. That's what is giving you the complaint about `--prune-empty` (complete with leading blank). The second complaint indicates that your `<commit_1_sha_id>` is at or after `HEAD`, which is not surprising if you are creating a new branch *at* that commit, as in your example code here.

Answer (score 4):

[BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) was really designed exactly for this case. I did read the "P.S. We do not have lfs or bfg installed in our project space." part of your question, but this still leaves you with two possibilities:

- Install BFG. If you have Java installed on your machine, it's just a `.jar` file to download.
- Use another machine. Using BFG is a one-time operation, you don't need to have it installed on your usual machine, just to have access to a machine where you can run BFG once, do the filtering, and use the resulting repo everywhere.