# Gitignore doesn't work on .xml files and /target directory

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

I have a two `.gitignore` files because one didn't work in the past and I had to create the second one; they which looks:

```
/target/
.idea/
```

and `.gitignore.gitignore` which looks:

```
*/target/**
/target/**
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
target/

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
.idea/

### NetBeans ###
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
.nb-gradle/
```

and still it includes those files which are in `.gitignore` - why?[image]

Comment: Did you try removing on of the .gitignore files ?

Comment: Should I remove .gitignore file? I haven't done it..

Comment: Just keep the one that has the configuration that u require. because it may be causing any kind of conflict when git tries commit

Comment: Have you committed those files before? The workspace.xml and application.properties

Comment: You should try to also add: `.idea/*.*`

Comment: I deleted .gitignore.gitignore and still has those errors. Yes I used to commit them..

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/936290/5295199

Comment: @AlanPerez doesn't work for me

Comment: git rm --cached ../../../../.idea/workspace.xml
git rm --cached ../../../../target/classes/application.properties

This should remove the files from the repository

Comment: I did it and still can't change the branch because:
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    ../../../../.idea/workspace.xml
        deleted:    ../../../../target/classes/application.properties

Comment: I commited it and still has the same file `modified`: Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ../../../../.idea/workspace.xml

Comment: This means the gitignore is not properly setup. Delete the custom one you wrote and use the .gitignore.gitignore by renaming it to .gitignore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.gitignore` only works for *untracked* files. If files are already part of `HEAD` revision, then `.gitignore` won't be considered for it. If you want to remove the file from previous revisions, you should consider rewriting history to get rid of them from the history of your branch.

Comment: how to rewrite that history?

Comment: Take your pick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history

Comment: `uncommitted` is wrong. `untracked` is correct. As soon as the file is tracked (`git add -- file`), `.gitignore` is out of the game, not just after you committed.

Comment: Corrected on the response. Thanks!